# In R data.table, how do I pass variable parameters to an expression?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, data.table

I am stuck with a small R issue with `data.table`. Your help is much appreciated. How do I do this:

```
getResult <- function(dt, expr, gby) {
  e <- substitute(expr)
  b <- substitute(gby)
  return(dt[,eval(e),by=b])
}

v1 <- "Sepal.Length"
v2 <- "Species"

dt <- data.table(iris)
rDT <- getResult(dt, sum(v1, na.rm=TRUE), v2)
```

I get following error:

> Error in sum(v1, na.rm = TRUE) : invalid 'type' (character) of
>   argument

Now, both `v1` and `v2` get passed from other program as character variable so I can't do this `v1<- quote(Sepal.Length)` which seems to work.

Comment: This may put you on the right track: `dt[, sum(get(v1), na.rm=TRUE), by=v2]` or suggest an alternative approach if you are flexible.

Comment: Thx. It worked, what happened? Function gets the object named v1. What did the substitute function did to this expression? Did it not do anything and tried to replace v1 with character value "Sepal.Length"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An alternative to flodel's answer in the comments could be

```
e <- parse(text = paste0("sum(", v1, ", na.rm = TRUE)"))

b <- parse(text = v2)

rDT2 <- dt[, eval(e), by = eval(b)]

#               b    V1
# [1,]     setosa 250.3
# [2,] versicolor 296.8
# [3,]  virginica 329.4
```

**EDIT:**

And to put this into a function,

```
getResult <- function(dt, expr, gby){
  return(dt[, eval(expr), by = eval(gby)])
}

(dtR <- getResult(dt = dt, expr = e, gby = b))
# gives the same result as above
```

**EDIT from Matthew:**
There's a subtle reason why the `paste0` and `eval` \ `quote` methods can be faster than `get` in some cases, too. One of the reasons grouping can be fast is that `data.table` inspects `j` to see which columns it uses, then only subsets those used columns (FAQ 1.12 and 3.1). It uses `base::all.vars(j)` to do that. When using `get()` in `j` the column being used is hidden from `all.vars` and `data.table` falls back to subsetting all the columns just in case the `j` expression needs them (much like when the `.SD` symbol is used in `j`, for which `.SDcols` was added to solve). If all the columns are used anyway then it doesn't make a difference, but if `DT` is say 1e7x100 then a grouped `j=sum(V1)` should be much faster than a grouped `j=sum(get("V1"))` for that reason. At least, that's what's supposed to happen, and if it doesn't then it may be a bug. If on the other hand many queries are being constructed dynamically and repeated then the time to `paste0` and `parse` might come into it. All depends really. Setting `verbose=TRUE` should print out a message about which columns have been detected as used by `j`, so that can be checked.

Comment: Thanks, going back the original question, how do I do this with your solution   getResult <- function(dt, expr, gby) {
  print(dt[,eval(expr), by=eval(b)])
}
v1 <- "Sepal.Length"
v2 <- "Species"
e <- parse(text = paste("sum(", v1, ", na.rm = TRUE)"))
b <- parse(text = v2)
#rDT2 <- dt[, eval(e), by = eval(b)]
dtR <- getResult(dt, e, b)

Comment: @user1157129, Sorry for the omission of the function as requested in your question. Please see the edit for a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry Ben, it is not working, am I goofing up something? getResult <- function(dt, expr, gby) {
  return(dt[,eval(expr), by=eval(gby)])
}
dt <- data.table(iris)
v1 <- "Sepal.Length"
v2 <- "Species"
e <- parse(text = paste("sum(", v1, ", na.rm = TRUE)"))
b <- parse(text = v2)
dtR <- getResult(dt = dt, expr = e, gby = b)

Comment: @user1157129, copying your above code and inserting line breaks (and loading the data.table package) works for me using R 2.15.0 and data.table 1.8.0 - are you getting an error message? What isn't working?

Comment: I get following error Ben - Error in names(byval) = as.character(bysuborig) : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: @user1157129, I get this error using R 2.13.1 patched and data.table 1.7.10 - would you be able to upgrade to the latest versions of the two packages?

Comment: Yes, the upgrades to R 2.15 and data.table 1.8 fixed this issue. Thanks Ben for your help!