# Dynamic subset condition in R

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to implement a function which takes a dynamic subset based on a list of column names of any length

The static code is:

```
s <- c("s0","s1","s2")
d.subset <- d[ d$s0 > 0 | d$s1 > 0 | d$s2 > 0,]
```

However, I want to generate the `d$s0 > 0 | d$s1 > 0 | d$s2 > 0` part based on s. I tried as.formula() for generating it, but it gave me an "invalid formula" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(s0 = c(0,1,0,0), s1 = c(1,1,1,0), s2 = c(0,1,1,0))

s <- c("s0","s1","s2")
```

Here is an easy solution with `rowSums`:

```
d[as.logical(rowSums(d[s] > 0)), ]
```

The result:

```
  s0 s1 s2
1  0  1  0
2  1  1  1
3  0  1  1
```

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, hmm, not sure I get you. `rowSums(d[s])` would give you `c(1, 3, 2, 0)`, and `rowSums(d[s]) > 0` would give you `c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)`, a logical value for each row determined by whether any of the columns are > 0.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Sorry, this was a mistake. I played around with some examples. Of course, the result of `rowSums` here is `c(1, 3, 2, 0)`. Now, I also realised the different position of the brackets in your comment. Agreed, a good idea as long as the data frame contains non-negative values only.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein The length of the value returned by `rowSums` will always be equal to the number of rows in the `data.frame`....

Answer (score 2):

You're code isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so this is a shot in the dark at what you want  I think you want to use indexing rather than the `$` operator:

```
s <- c("s0","s1","s2")
d.subset <- d[ d[, s[1]] > 0 | d[, s[2]] > 0 | d[, s[3]] > 0,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answer from @sven-hohenstein here is a generalised function that will filter based on a list of predicates, specified in the form `column=list(binary_operator, rhs)` (e.g. `` x=list(`<=`, 3) `` for `x <= 3`).

```
#' Filter a data frame dynamically
#'
#' @param df data frame to filter
#' @param controls list of filters (with optional operators)
filter_data = function(df, controls) {

  evaluate = function(predicate, value) {
    if (is.list(predicate)) {
      operator = predicate[[1L]]
      rhs = predicate[[2L]]
    } else {
      operator = `==`
      rhs = predicate
    }
    return(operator(value, rhs))
  }

  index = apply(
    mapply(evaluate, predicate=controls, value=df[names(controls)]), 1L, all
  )

  return(df[index, ])

}
```

Here is an example using the filtering function to apply the condition `x == 2 & y <= 2.5 & z != 'C'`:

```
# create example data
df = data.frame(
  x=sample(1:3, 100L, TRUE),
  y=runif(100L, 1, 5),
  z=sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 100L, TRUE)
)

controls = list(x=2L, y=list(`<=`, 2.5), z=list(`!=`, 'C'))

filter_data(df, controls)
```

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: This solution is strongly not recommended. Please see comments and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) for details.)

I just learned this trick: write it all as a character string and use `eval(parse(text=`. Perhaps not the best thing for this example but it can be used more generally.

```
s <- c("s0","s1","s2")
s.1 <- paste0("d$",s," > 0",collapse=" | ")
d.subset <- eval(parse(text=paste0("d[",s.1,",]")))
```

Comment: -1 this is hideous. to quote R core contributor Thomas Lumley, "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question". addtional reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse

Comment: Thanks - I got this off of an old data.table question without knowing any of the pitfalls. I've learned something new today.

Comment: if you feel like adding anything, I'd be glad to remove the down vote.

Comment: Something like "EDIT: This is never recommended"?