# R function to make table won't work

Tags: r

I need to make a million tables, so rather than loop, I'm trying to functionalize my code.  However, I can't get a function to work, and I can't figure out why.  Here are some example data to work with:

```
  # example data:
set.seed(1)
dframe <- data.frame(time=c(rep("before", 6), rep("after", 4)), 
                     Quest1=sample(0:5, 10, replace=TRUE))
dframe
  # result: 
     time Quest1
1  before      1
2  before      2
3  before      3
4  before      5
5  before      1
6  before      5
7   after      5
8   after      3
9   after      3
10  after      0
```

Here is the code I've tried:

```
  # works:
tab1 <- prop.table(with(dframe, table(time, factor(Quest1, c(0:5)))), 1)
tab1
  # result:
time         0     1     2     3     4     5
after  0.250 0.000 0.000 0.500 0.000 0.250
before 0.000 0.333 0.167 0.167 0.000 0.333

  # doesn't work:  
makeTab = function(data, rowVar, colVar) {
  prop.table(with(data, table(rowVar, factor(colVar, c(0:5)))), 1)
}
tab1 <- makeTab(dframe, time, Quest1)
  # result:
Error in factor(colVar, c(0:5)) : object 'Quest1' not found

  # works:
tab1 <- prop.table(table(dframe$time, factor(dframe$Quest1, c(0:5))), 1)
tab1
  # (result same as above)

  # doesn't work:  
makeTab = function(data, rowVar, colVar) {
  prop.table(table(data$rowVar, factor(data$colVar, c(0:5))), 1)
}
tab1 <- makeTab(dframe, time, Quest1)
tab1
  # result:
     0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Note that looping *does* work:

```
  # works:  
tab <- list()
for(i in 1:1){
  tab[[i]] <- prop.table(table(dframe$time, factor(dframe[,i+1], c(0:5))), 1)
}
tab
  # result:
[[1]]

             0     1     2     3     4     5
  after  0.250 0.000 0.000 0.500 0.000 0.250
  before 0.000 0.333 0.167 0.167 0.000 0.333
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `get`.  Your first example will work if you wrap `rowVar` and `colVar` in `get`

```
makeTab = function(data, rowVar, colVar) {
  prop.table(with(data, table(get(rowVar), factor(get(colVar), c(0:5)))), 1)
}
tab1=makeTab(dframe, 'time', 'Quest1')

tab1

#                 0         1         2         3         4         5
#  after  0.2500000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.2500000
#  before 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.3333333
```

Or in your second example use `[` rather than `$`.  Currently you're asking for the column `rowVar` rather than its value:

```
makeTab = function(data, rowVar, colVar) {
  prop.table(table(data[, rowVar], factor(data[, colVar], c(0:5))), 1)
}
```

Also note I'm passing the strings of my column names (`'Quest1'`) rather than an object named `Quest1`.

---

As Joran mentioned, the second option is probably preferable since using `get` can often have unforeseen consequences!

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works.  I'll use the latter suggestion. What is the principle at work here, though? I was unfamiliar w/ `get`, the code works fine if it's not embedded in a function. W/ the function you need 2 things: the alternative code, & the quotation marks. Why does the function make it different from straight code or loop?

Comment: @gung The code is not the same.  You've replaced names of columns with variables that contain the name of the columns in your first function.  So instead you need to use `get` to get the value of the variable out.   In general, I find that `with` and the ways it works can be confusing at best. I only use it when I want to write less, instead opt for the subsetting choice using `[` especially programatically.

Comment: the second version is probably safer and is more in line with what R users usually do.

Answer (score 4):

Because you mentioned millions of tables and I fear from your loop construct you intend to use loops (e.g., `lapply`), here is an alternative to do two (or more) columns:

```
set.seed(1)
dframe <- data.frame(time=c(rep("before", 6), rep("after", 4)), 
                     Quest1=sample(0:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
                     Quest2=sample(0:5, 10, replace=TRUE))

library(reshape2)
dframe <- melt(dframe,id.vars="time")

tab <- prop.table(table(dframe$time,factor(dframe$value, c(0:5)),dframe$variable), 
                  c(1,3))

# , ,  = Quest1
# 
# 
#                0         1         2         3         4         5
# after  0.2500000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.2500000
# before 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.0000000 0.3333333
# 
# , ,  = Quest2
# 
# 
#                0         1         2         3         4         5
# after  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2500000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.2500000
# before 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0000000
```

Comment: Is `lapply` just a loop in disguise?

Comment: Slightly optimized, but yes. It's not a vectorized approach, i.e. not significantly faster than the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for this, btw. FTR, I'm not really making a *million* tables--I was exaggerating--it's more like about 30.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to the design of your function, you can use `eval` too.

```
makeTab = function(data, rowVar, colVar)
    prop.table(with(data, table(eval(rowVar), factor(eval(colVar), 0:5))), 1)

makeTab(dframe, time, Quest1)
##              0       1       2       3       4       5
## after  0.25000 0.00000 0.00000 0.50000 0.00000 0.25000
## before 0.00000 0.33333 0.16667 0.16667 0.00000 0.33333
```

Comment: for posterity [The dangers of eval(parse(...))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

Comment: @Justin I use quite often though...but was useful to go through this discussion. thks