# Passing parameters to with() via function

Tags: r

There is a way to pass a parameter from a function to `with()`? Something like:

```
dados <- data.frame(x=1:10, v1=rnorm(10), v2=rnorm(10))

with(dados, v1+v2) # Works

func <- function(data, funcao) {
 with(data, funcao)
}

func(dados, v1+v2) # Fails
func(dados, 'v1+v2') # Fails
```

I've already tried with `eval()`, but it fails too :/

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. The real question is why you would want that. `with` is for interactive use.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I just wanna save dozens of line like `dados$index <- dados$v1 + dados$v2` (like the example, my indexes are more complicated) adding the formula to the function's call. You can change `with()` for `evalq()`, or anything that works.

Comment: There's probably an easier (and less buggy) way to do what you're trying to do than creating this function.

Comment: I still don't understand. `lapply(list_of_data.frames, function(df) {df$index <- df$v1 + df$v2; df})`?

Comment: v1 and v2 are only examples. I have tons of indexes, some are directly the variable and others are functions of 2 or more variables (with names from V0001 to V1100). I have a functions that return the data frame with only the columns I need, and now I want add the 'feature' to compute the index inside the function.

Comment: It may also help you to read my question, & the answers, here: [R function to make table won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17600713/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i think i got it. You need to call *eval* inside *func* and then pass an *expression*:

```
dados <- data.frame(x=1:10, v1=rnorm(10), v2=rnorm(10))

func <- function(data, funcao) {
     with(data, eval(funcao))
}

func(dados, expression(v1+v2))

[1] -0.9950362  1.0934899 -0.9791810 -1.2420633 -1.0930204  0.8941630 -2.3307571 -1.5012386  3.2731584  0.2585419
```

To use a string:

```
x = "v1 + v2"
func(dados, parse(text=x))

[1] -0.9950362  1.0934899 -0.9791810 -1.2420633 -1.0930204  0.8941630 -2.3307571 -1.5012386  3.2731584  0.2585419
```

Comment: Almost there! Any idea how to allow `funcao` be a string? `as.expression()` didn't work

Comment: Perfect! I just changed the function to `func <- function(data, funcao) { funcao <- parse(text=funcao) ; return(with(data, eval(funcao))) }` so I can use directly a string. Thanks!