# dplyr without hard-coding the variable names

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to use dplyr's mutate function without hard-coding the variable names? For example, the following code works, because I hard-code the name Var1:

```
            > d=expand.grid(1:3, 20:22)
            > d
            Var1 Var2
            1    1   20
            2    2   20
            3    3   20
            4    1   21
            5    2   21
            6    3   21
            7    1   22
            8    2   22
            9    3   22
            > d=mutate(d, x=percent_rank(Var1))
            > d
            Var1 Var2     x
            1    1   20 0.000
            2    2   20 0.375
            3    3   20 0.750
            4    1   21 0.000
            5    2   21 0.375
            6    3   21 0.750
            7    1   22 0.000
            8    2   22 0.375
            9    3   22 0.750
```

However, when I make the variable's name a variable, it no longer works:

```
            > my.variable='Var1'
            > d=mutate(d, x=percent_rank(my.variable))
            > d
                Var1 Var2   x
            1    1   20 NaN
            2    2   20 NaN
            3    3   20 NaN
            4    1   21 NaN
            5    2   21 NaN
            6    3   21 NaN
            7    1   22 NaN
            8    2   22 NaN
            9    3   22 NaN
```

The eval() and as.symbol() functions don't seem to help, either.

Comment: why do you want to do this? You are setting x equal to the `percent_rank` of a character string. What else would you expect to happen?

Answer (score 10):

The great Hadley Wickham himself (hallowed be his name!) suggested [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/cr9PzNEtz6w) on the `mutatr` Google Groups:

```
d <- expand.grid(1:3, 20:22)
my.variable <- 'Var1'
percent_rank <- function(x) rank(x)/max(rank(x))
call <- substitute(mutate(d, percent_rank(var)), 
                   list(var = as.name(my.variable)))
eval(call)
#   Var1 Var2 percent_rank(Var1)
# 1    1   20              0.250
# 2    2   20              0.625
# 3    3   20              1.000
# 4    1   21              0.250
# 5    2   21              0.625
# 6    3   21              1.000
# 7    1   22              0.250
# 8    2   22              0.625
# 9    3   22              1.000
```

Comment: +1, although I would prefer a solution which does not include `eval`. But, hey, if it is good enough for Hadley :).

Comment: why u no like `eval`?

Comment: The main point is that `eval` is normally not needed, and less obscure solutions are present. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse.

Comment: I agree as far as things like `eval(parse(text="<string>"))` are concerned, but I don't think avoiding `eval` is possible when you programmatically construct a `call`.

Comment: It is just that using eval to construct the call is a bit of a hack, native support for using strings would be preferable.

Comment: Agreed. It would be much nicer if `dplyr` could deal with this type of thing without forcing us to resort to this kind of "computing on the language". I'm sure that will come though, it's still in beta.

Comment: Yes, it's on the to do list. In the interim, I much prefer this sort of solution to using get with a custom environment. It's parse that's the problem, not eval.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `get` and precise the environment in which the object "Var1" is.

```
> my.variable = 'Var1'
> mutate(d, x = percent_rank(get(my.variable, envir = as.environment(d))))
  Var1 Var2     x
1    1   20 0.000
2    2   20 0.375
3    3   20 0.750
4    1   21 0.000
5    2   21 0.375
6    3   21 0.750
7    1   22 0.000
8    2   22 0.375
9    3   22 0.750
```

I suggest you to read more about "non-standard evaluation" on the "Advanced R programming" wiki by Hadley Wickham : http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

## EDIT

This answer was recently voted so I realized that the solution I gave a year and a half ago was not really great and I take this opportunity to upgrade my answer.

Since dplyr 0.3 you can use standard evaluation version of dplyr's functions, using their "fun_" versions.

Also you have to use `interp` from lazyeval package if you are doing some computations on the variables :

```
my.variable = "Var1"
expr <- lazyeval::interp(~percent_rank(x), x = as.name(my.variable))
mutate_(d, .dots = setNames(list(expr), "x"))
Var1 Var2     x
1    1   20 0.000
2    2   20 0.375
3    3   20 0.750
4    1   21 0.000
5    2   21 0.375
6    3   21 0.750
7    1   22 0.000
8    2   22 0.375
9    3   22 0.750
```

Answer (score 3):

In the devel version of `dplyr` (awaiting new release `0.6.0`), with the introduction of `quosures` and unquote functions (`!!`, `UQ`) to evaluate the quotes in `group_by/summarise/mutate`, this becomes more easier

```
 my.variable <- quo(Var1)
 percent_rank <- function(x) rank(x)/max(rank(x))
 d %>% 
   mutate(x = percent_rank(!!my.variable))
#  Var1 Var2     x
#1    1   20 0.250
#2    2   20 0.625
#3    3   20 1.000
#4    1   21 0.250
#5    2   21 0.625
#6    3   21 1.000
#7    1   22 0.250
#8    2   22 0.625
#9    3   22 1.000
```

It also has other features to pass column names

```
mynewvar <- 'x'
d %>% 
   mutate(!!mynewvar := percent_rank(!!my.variable))
#  Var1 Var2     x
#1    1   20 0.250
#2    2   20 0.625
#3    3   20 1.000
#4    1   21 0.250
#5    2   21 0.625
#6    3   21 1.000
#7    1   22 0.250
#8    2   22 0.625
#9    3   22 1.000
```

We can also create a function and pass the argument

```
f1 <- function(dat, myvar, colN){
  myvar <- enquo(myvar)
  colN <- quo_name(enquo(colN))
 
  dat %>%
      mutate(!!colN := percent_rank(!!myvar))
 }

f1(d, Var1, x)
#  Var1 Var2     x
#1    1   20 0.250
#2    2   20 0.625
#3    3   20 1.000
#4    1   21 0.250
#5    2   21 0.625
#6    3   21 1.000
#7    1   22 0.250
#8    2   22 0.625
#9    3   22 1.000
```

In the above function, `enquo` does the similar functionality as `substitute` from `base R` in taking the user input arguments and converting it to `quosure`.  As we need column name in string, we can use `quo_name` to do the conversion to string and the evaluation inside the `mutate` call is done by unquoting (`!!` or `UQ`)

#### data

```
d <- expand.grid(1:3, 20:22)
```