# Flagging groups in which all members fulfill a certain requirement in R

Tags: r, grouping, data-manipulation

Suppose the data below:

```
GroupId <-          c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
IndId <-            c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5)
IndGroupProperty <- c(1,2,1,2,3,3,4,5,6)
PropertyType <-     c(1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2)

df <- data.frame(GroupId, IndId, IndGroupProperty, PropertyType)
df
```

These are multi-level data, where each group `GroupId` consists of one or multiple individuals `IndId` having access to one or more properties `IndGroupProperty`, which are unique to their respective group (i.e. property 1 belongs to group 1 and no other group). These properties each belong to a type `PropertyType`.

The task is to flag each row with a dummy variable where there is at least one type-1 property belonging to each individual in the group.

For our sample data, this simply is:

```
ValidGroup <-       c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(df, ValidGroup)
df
```

The first four rows are flagged with a 1, because each individual (1, 2) of group (1) has access to a type-1 property (1).
The three subsequent rows belong to group (2), in which only individual (4) has access to a type-1 property (4). Thus these are not flagged (0).
The last two rows also receives no flag. Group (3) consists only of a single individual (5) with access to two type-2 properties (5, 6).

I have looked into several commands: `levels` seems to lack group support; `getGroups` in the `nlme` package does not like the input of my real data; I guess that there might be something useful in `doBy`, but `summaryBy` does not seem to take `levels` as a function.

Solution EDIT: `dplyr` solution by Henrik wrapped into a function:

```
foobar <- function(object, group, ind, type){
groupvar <- deparse(substitute(group)) 
indvar <- deparse(substitute(ind)) 
typevar <- deparse(substitute(type)) 
eval(substitute(
object[, c(groupvar, indvar, typevar)] %.%
  group_by(group, ind) %.%
  mutate(type1 = any(type == 1))  %.%
  group_by(group, add = FALSE) %.%
  mutate(ValidGroup = all(type1) * 1) %.%
  select(-type1)
  ))
}
```

Comment: A nicely posed question like this (with reproducible code, and showing what you already looked at) makes me want to help you a lot more than many less-nicely posed questions around here...

Comment: @StephanKolassa, Thank you! I am new to R and have a lot of questions, so I quickly learned how to pose them to get the answer I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try `ave`:

```
# for each individual within group, calculate number of 1s in PropertyType
v1 <- with(df, ave(PropertyType, list(GroupId, IndId), FUN = function(x) sum(x == 1)))

# within each group, check if all v1 is 1.
# The boolean result is coerced to 1 and 0 by ave.  
df$ValidGroup <- ave(v1, df$GroupId, FUN = function(x) all(x == 1))

#   GroupId IndId IndGroupProperty PropertyType ValidGroup
# 1       1     1                1            1          1
# 2       1     1                2            2          1
# 3       1     2                1            1          1
# 4       1     2                2            2          1
# 5       2     3                3            2          0
# 6       2     4                3            2          0
# 7       2     4                4            1          0
# 8       3     5                5            2          0
# 9       3     5                6            2          0
```

**Edit** Added `dplyr` alternative and benchmark for data sets of different size: original data, and data that are 10 and 100 times larger than original.

First wrap up the alternatives in functions:

```
fun_ave <- function(df){
  v1 <- with(df, ave(PropertyType, list(GroupId, IndId), FUN = function(x) sum(x == 1)))
df$ValidGroup <- ave(v1, list(df$GroupId), FUN = function(x) all(x == 1))
df  
}

library(dplyr)
fun_dp <- function(df){
df %.%
  group_by(GroupId, IndId) %.%
  mutate(
    type1 = any(PropertyType == 1)) %.%
  group_by(GroupId, add = FALSE) %.%
  mutate(
    ValidGroup = all(type1) * 1) %.%
  select(-type1)
}


fun_by <- function(df){
  bar <- by(data=df,INDICES=df$GroupId,FUN=function(xx){
    foo <- table(xx$IndId,xx$PropertyType)
    if ( !("1" %in% colnames(foo)) ) {
      return(FALSE)   # no PropertyType=1 at all in this group
    } else {
      return(all(foo[,"1"]>0))    # return whether all IndId have an 1 entry
    }})
  cbind(df,ValidGroup = as.integer(bar[as.character(df$GroupId)]))
}
```

**Benchmarks**

Original data:

```
microbenchmark(
  fun_ave(df),
  fun_dp(df),
  fun_by(df))

# Unit: microseconds
#        expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# fun_ave(df)  497.964  519.8215  538.8275  563.5355   651.535   100
#  fun_dp(df)  851.861  870.6765  931.1170  968.5590  1760.360   100
#  fun_by(df) 1343.743 1412.5455 1464.6225 1581.8915 12588.607   100
```

On a tiny data set `ave` is about twice as fast as `dplyr` and more than 2.5 times faster than `by`.

Generate some larger data; 10 times the number of groups and individuals

```
GroupId <- sample(1:30, 100, replace = TRUE)
IndId <- sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
PropertyType <- sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(GroupId, IndId, PropertyType)

microbenchmark(
  fun_ave(df2),
  fun_dp(df2),
  fun_by(df2))
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr      min       lq    median        uq       max neval
#  fun_ave(df2) 2.928865 3.185259  3.270978  3.435002  5.151457   100
#   fun_dp(df2) 1.079176 1.231226  1.273610  1.352866  2.717896   100
#   fun_by(df2) 9.464359 9.855317 10.137180 10.484994 12.445680   100
```

`dplyr` is three times faster than `ave` and nearly 10 times faster than `by`.

100 times the number of groups and individuals

```
GroupId <- sample(1:300, 1000, replace = TRUE)
IndId <- sample(1:500, 1000, replace = TRUE)
PropertyType <- sample(1:2, 1000, replace = TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(GroupId, IndId, PropertyType)

microbenchmark(
  fun_ave(df2),
  fun_dp(df2),
  fun_by(df2))

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min         lq    median        uq      max neval
# fun_ave(df2) 337.889895 392.983915 413.37554 441.58179 549.5516   100
#  fun_dp(df2)   3.253872   3.477195   3.58173   3.73378  75.8730   100
#  fun_by(df2)  92.248791 102.122733 104.09577 109.99285 186.6829   100
```

`ave` is really loosing ground now. `dplyr` is nearly 30 times faster than `by`, and more than 100 times faster than `ave`.

Comment: While conceptually this should work, using your version with `ave` leads my R to try to allocate 25gb of RAM, which is way over my 8gb... :/

Comment: But it's a nice illustration, +1. I originally tried something similar, but I'm more fluent in `by()` than in `ave()`, so I'll meditate on this solution a bit more to learn.

Comment: @iraserd, recently I faced a similar setting with my own data and I needed a solution faster than `ave` and `by`, so I tried `dplyr`. I have updated my answer with a `dplyr` alternative and benchmarks for data of different sizes. `dplyr` is considerably faster than both `ave` and `by` when data sets are getting larger.

Comment: @Henrik alright, it works and indeed produces the same result as the `by` version in only 0.68 seconds, while `by` take 9.61 minutes!
However, some caveats: first, your `dply` version behaves oddly with other variables in larger data frames (I got an error for some dummy variable). This is easily circumvented by changing line 2 of your function definition to `df[, c("GroupId", "IndId", PropertyType")] %.%` and then appending the restult column to the original data frame.
Second point is that I cannot manage to wrap `dply` into a function in the same format as Stephan Kolassa above. Ideas?

Comment: @Henrik - details of my function wrapping: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, named_dots(...), environment()) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name`. Code is: `foobar <- function(object, group, ind, type){
object[, c(group, ind, type)] %.%
  group_by(object[,group], object[,ind]) %.%
  mutate(
    type1 = any(object[,type] == 1)) %.%
  group_by(object[,group], add = FALSE) %.%
  mutate(
    ValidGroup = all(type1) * 1) %.%
  select(-type1)
}
`

Comment: I might have ideas, but it is hard to tell without a reproducible example. My function worked for the data you provided in OP. You need to be clearer than "behaves oddly" and "got an error". Regarding benchmarks, please note `"Unit: milliseconds"`.

Comment: Regarding the benchmark units, that was a silly misconception on my behalf.
Regarding proper formulation of the behaviour for my real dataset: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  column 'DateDiff' has unsupported type` in `traceback()` line nr 27 `27: stop(list(message = "column 'DateDiff' has unsupported type", 
        call = eval(expr, envir, enclos), cppstack = NULL))`
Where `DateDiff`is a variable of class "difftime" generated by substracting two class "Date" variables from each other (which is obviously not a dummy - another mistake on my behalf).

Comment: For "wrap dply into a function in the same format as Stephan Kolassa above", these posts may be relevant: [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005419/dplyr-without-hard-coding-the-variable-names) and [**here**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/cr9PzNEtz6w) (with answer by dplyr-Hadley)

Comment: So you don't use the `Datediff` variable in the actual `dply` call, it is 'just' an additional variable?

Comment: Having a look into your links and see if I can construct the appropriate call.
Correct, the `Datediff` variable is just some co-variate in the data frame (which has in total about 50 variables) and no action should be performed on it.

Comment: I added a variable of `Class 'difftime'` to you toy data and got the same error. One possible work-around is to convert the `difftime` variable to `numeric`, something like `as.numeric(difftime(df$date2, df$date1, unit = "days"))`.

Comment: That would work, or selecting only the needed columns and cbinding the column after manipulation, which needs no manipulation of the other variables.
However, I still can't manage to wrap the thing into a function. Trying to use substitute but I think I don't understand how the variables I define in `function` are handled later by `substitute(mutate())`. I imagine that by calling `foobar`, the arguments get substituted by the strings and object supplied for the arguments (`foobar(object, string, string, string)`). But I think I'm completely wrong here...

Comment: `foobar <- function(object, group, ind, type){
object[, c(group, ind, type)] %.%
  group_by(object[,group], object[,ind]) %.%
  substitute(mutate(type1 = any(typevar == 1)), list(typevar = as.name(type)))   %.%
  group_by(object[,group], add = FALSE) %.%
  mutate(
    ValidGroup = all(type1) * 1) %.%
  select(-type1)
}`
 Where I added the `substitute()`

Comment: I haven't used the methods described in the links I provided, so I'm afraid I can't help you much further with this particular issue. Please feel free to post a new question with a self-contained minimal example together with the code you have tried so far, posting explicit error messages, possibly referring to relevant earlier posts. Good luck!

Comment: @Henrik - with some help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062314/using-paste-and-substitute-in-combination-with-quotation-marks-in-r) I finally managed to wrap it into a function. I will edit it into the OP for later reference.

Comment: @iraserd, FYI: I submitted an [issue on `dplyr` github on the problem with the `difftime` variable](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/390)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bar <- by(data=df,INDICES=df$GroupId,FUN=function(xx){
    foo <- table(xx$IndId,xx$PropertyType)
    if ( !("1" %in% colnames(foo)) ) {
        return(FALSE)   # no PropertyType=1 at all in this group
    } else {
        return(all(foo[,"1"]>0))    # return whether all IndId have an 1 entry
    }})
cbind(df,bar[as.character(df$GroupId)])
```

The key is using `by()` to apply a function *by* a grouping variable, here your `df$GroupId`. The function to apply is an anonymous function. For each chunk (defined by the grouping variable), it creates a `table` of the `IndId` and `PropertyType` entries. It then looks whether "1" appears at all in the `PropertyType` - if not, it returns `FALSE`, if yes, it looks whether every `IndId` has at least one "1" entry (i.e., whether all entries in the "1" column of the `table` are >0).

We store the result of the `by()` call in a structure `bar`, which is named according to the levels in the grouping variable. This in turn allows us to roll the result back out to the original `data.frame`. Note how I am using `as.character()` here to make sure the integers are interpreted as entry *names*, not entry *numbers*. Bad Things often happen when things have names that can be interpreted as numbers.

If you really want a 0-1 result instead of `TRUE-FALSE`, just add an `as.numeric()`.

---

EDIT. Let's turn this into a function.

```
foobar <- function(object, group, ind, type) {
    bar <- by(data=object,INDICES=object[,group],FUN=function(xx){
        foo <- table(xx[,ind],xx[,type])
        if ( !("1" %in% colnames(foo)) ) {
            return(FALSE)   # no PropertyType=1 at all in this group
        } else {
            return(all(foo[,"1"]>0))    # return whether all IndId have an 1 entry
        }})
    cbind(object,bar[as.character(object[,group])])
}

foobar(df,"GroupId","IndId","PropertyType")
```

This still requires that the target be exactly "1", but of course this could also be included in the function definition as a parameter. Just be sure to keep *column names* and *variables that contain column names* straight.

Comment: Bonus question: how do I wrap this into a new function that takes as input the dataframe, GroupID, IndID and PropertyType?
`foobar <- function(object,group,ind,type) { ... }` and in the curly braces replace the respective values in the function?
When I then call `foobar(df, GroupId, IndId, PropertyType)` I get `Error in by.data.frame(data = object, INDICES = object$group, FUN = function(xx) { : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]`

Comment: `foobar <- function(object, group, ind, type) {
bar <- by(data=object,INDICES=object$group,FUN=function(xx){
    foo <- table(xx$ind,xx$type)
    if ( !("1" %in% colnames(foo)) ) {
        return(FALSE)   # no type=1 at all in this group
    } else {
        return(all(foo[,"1"]>0))    # return whether all ind have an 1 entry
    }})
cbind(object,bar[as.character(object$group)])
}

foobar(df, GroupId, IndId, PropertyType)
`

Comment: I edited my answer to turn it into a function. Your homework will be to do the same with @Henrik's `ave`-based approach ;-)

Comment: Great, would give another +1! But what the h*, why do I suddenly need `[,]` instead of `$`!
Homework done: `foobar2 <- function(object, group, ind, type) {
 v1 <- with(object, ave(object[,type], list(object[,group],object[,ind]), FUN = function(x) sum(x ==1 )))
 object$ValidGroup <- ave(v1, object[,group], FUN = function(x) sum(x == 0) == 0)
}
foobar2(df, "GroupId", "IndId", "PropertyType")`

Comment: Writing R functions can be really confusing to me as I come from a Stata background where in functions I simply refer to the arguments of the function via local macros during the call, where the macros are literally replaced by the arguments provided...

Comment: `foo$bar` accesses the component (column of a `data.frame` or entry in a `list`) called "bar" in `foo`. `foo[,bar]` accesses the column(s) in `foo` whose name(s) match *the value* of the variable `bar`. Confused now? ;-)

Comment: And in defining the `foobar <- function(foo, bar)` and calling it with `foobar(df, GroupId)`, "GroupId" becomes _the value_ of `bar` and thus needs to be referred to with `foo[,bar]`.

Comment: What is strange is that I simply added `object <- cbind ...` to automatically bind the column at the end of the function, but when I check after the function runs, the column is not there.

Comment: Do you return `object` at the end of the function? Either by simply writing `object` on a line by itself, or using the (in my eyes, clearer) `return(object)`?

Comment: Tried that now. When I include `return(object)` in the function as the last line before `}`, it prints the data frame including the new column. When I the type `df` to view the data frame, the column is no longer there.

Comment: ... `object <- cbind(object,bar[as.numeric(object[,group])])
return(object)
}

foobar(df, "GroupId", "IndId", "PropertyType")
df
`

Comment: R calls by value, not by reference. Your function won't modify the *global* variable `df`, only the local variable `object`. Do `df <- foobar(df, ...)` (although I would rather assign the result to a new object; overwriting objects with function results makes debugging hard).

Comment: So simple but so hard to see - something tells me I should have taken some courses in computer science ... :)

Comment: changed correct answer to Henrik's because of increased efficiency - you might want to have a look!