# passing function argument to dplyr select

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

To select a couple columns from a dataframe I can do

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2, 3), col2=letters[1:3], col3=LETTERS[4:6])

df %>%
  select(col1, col2)
```

I want to write a function similar to

```
f <- function(data, firstCol, secondCol){
   data %>%
    select(substitute(firstCol), substitute(secondCol))
}
```

But running `f(df, col1, col2)` gives me the error

```
Error in select_vars(names(.data), ..., env = parent.frame()) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Called from: (function () 
{
    .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)
})()
```

**EDIT** -- slightly less trivial example:

Suppose I wanted to do

```
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, hp) %>%
  unique %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(avgHP = mean(hp))
```

but with different datasets and different variable names. I could reuse the code and replace `mtcars`, `cyl`, and `hp`. But I'd rather wrap it all up in a function

Comment: Perhaps [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005419/dplyr-without-hard-coding-the-variable-names) (with an answer by @hadley) is relevant?

Comment: Just curious. Did anybody solve the slightly less trivial example in the end?

Comment: @tim see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html quite a bit of things have changed since last year

Comment: @organicagave Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple in this case, since you can just use ...

```
f <- function(data, ...) {
  data %>% select(...)
}

f(df, col1, col2)

#>   col1 col2
#> 1    1    a
#> 2    2    b
#> 3    3    c
```

In the more general case, you have two options:

1. Wait until https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/352 is closed
2. Construct the complete expression using `substitute()` and then
   `eval()`

Comment: In fact, in this case you can even use: `f <- select` .

Answer (score 5):

Since rlang version 0.4.0, the curly-curly `{{` operator would be a better solution.

```
f <- function(data, firstCol, secondCol){
   data %>%
    select({{ firstCol }}, {{ secondCol }})
}

df <- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2, 3), col2=letters[1:3], col3=LETTERS[4:6])

df %>% f(col1, col2)

#   col1 col2
# 1    1    a
# 2    2    b
# 3    3    c
```