# Non standard evaluation in R for loop: Unquoted input variable in a function containing dplyr summarise always returns NA, but filter function works

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse, nse

## SHORT SUMMARY

dplyr unquoting is failing as an argument of function `summarise` where the quoted object is the argument of a function the use of `summarise`, and that argument is assigned in a for loop.

**For Loop**

```
for(j in 1:1){
  sumvar  <- paste0("randnum",j)
  chkfunc(sumvar)
}
```

**Function (abbreviated here, shown in full below)**

```
chkfunc <- function(sumvar) {
sumvar <- enquo(sumvar)
[...]
    summarise(mn = mean(!!sumvar))
```

[image]

## LONG SUMMARY

I have two columns that sometimes contain NAs and I want to use [dplyr non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) and its famous unquoting (AKA bang bang `!!`) to summarise each column in one for loop.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(3)
randnum1 <- rnorm(10)
randnum1[randnum1<0] <- NA
randnum2 <- rnorm(10)
randnum2[randnum2<0] <- NA
randfrm <- data.frame(cbind(randnum1, randnum2))
print(randfrm)
```

[image]

We see below that the filter function processes the unquoting (!!) just fine but the summarise function fails, returning an "argument is not numeric or logical" error. The same occurs when I use `:=` in the summarise function call (not shown here), which appeared in the "[Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)" vignette. Finally, I confirmed that the *class* of `!!sumvar` is *numeric* within function `chkfunc`.

```
chkfunc <- function(sumvar) {
  sumvar <- enquo(sumvar)

  message("filter function worked with !!sumvar")
  outfrm <- randfrm %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!sumvar))
  print(outfrm)
  message("summarise function failed with !!sumvar")
  outfrm <- randfrm %>%
             filter(!is.na(!!sumvar)) %>%
             summarise(mn = mean(!!sumvar))
}
# Just one iteration to avoid confusion
for(j in 1:1){
  sumvar  <- paste0("randnum",j)
  chkfunc(sumvar)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I would like an answer using *dplyr*, the following works with `substitute` and `eval` rather than using *dplyr* functions (answer adapted from [Akrun's answer to StackOverflow question "Unquote string in R's substitute command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732838/unquote-string-in-rs-substitute-command)):

```
chkfunc <- function(sumvar) {
  outfrm <- eval(substitute(randfrm %>%
                            filter(!is.na(y)) %>%
                            summarise(mn = mean(y)),
                            list(y=as.name(sumvar))))
  print(outfrm)
} 

for(j in 1:2){
  sumvar  <- paste0("randnum",j)
  chkfunc(sumvar)
}

print(outfrm)
```

[image]

Finally, I'll note that while the `pull` function on `!!sumvar` showed the resulting class to be *numeric* (i.e., the same class and values of `randfrm$randnum1`), I figured out that `!!sumvar` is treated as a character string (i.e., `"randnum1`) in both my use of `filter` and `summarise`, hence the `argument is not numeric` warning.