# Finding the right order of recursion down a matrix of lists

Tags: r, recursion, matrix

This relates to my other question, and may help me get to a solution.  The following structure is a 3x1 matrix with each element containing a list.

```
cb <- structure(list(c("apples", "and", "pears"), c("one", "banana"
      ), c("pears", "oranges", "and", "pizza")), .Dim = c(3L, 1L),   
      .Dimnames = list(NULL, "s"))
```

I'd like to recursively assign 4 as the length of each matrix element, and then concatenate them all, so that the result is

```
# [1] "apples"  "and"     "pears"   NA        "one"     "banana"   
# [6]  NA        NA       "pears"   "oranges" "and"     "pizza"
```

Here's the manual way to do it.

```
`length<-`(cb[[1]],4)
# [1] "apples" "and"    "pears"  NA      
`length<-`(cb[[2]],4)
# [1] "one"    "banana" NA       NA      
`length<-`(cb[[3]],4)
# [1] "pears"   "oranges" "and"     "pizza"
```

I'd like to do this without looping, either by using recursion or writing a `bquote` expression.  I think I need to use `do.call`, but I can't figure out the right way to do it.  My code is right now is

```
do.call(`length<-`, list(c(cb, recursive=TRUE), 12))
# [1] "apples"  "and"     "pears"   "one"     "banana"  "pears"    
# [6] "oranges" "and"     "pizza"   NA        NA        NA
```

but this appends the `NA` values to the end of the concatenated vector, and I want to recursively append them because I probably will not know how many rows (list elements) `cb` contains.  There are `recursive =` arguments in both `unlist` and `c`, maybe those need to be used here.

An answer that replaces `x` with the current list level, like in the following, would work.

```
replicate(3, quote(`length<-`(cb[[x]], 4L)))
#[[1]]
#`length<-`(cb[[x]], 4L)  # x = 1
#
#[[2]]
#`length<-`(cb[[x]], 4L)  # x = 2
#
#[[3]]
#`length<-`(cb[[x]], 4L)  # x = 3
```

Comment: Somegthing like `lapply(cb, function(x){if(length(x) < 4){append(x, rep(NA, times = 4-length(x)))}else{x}})`?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention...no `*apply` functions.  I'll add that.

Comment: There are `recursive` arguments in `unlist` and `c` that I *know* are there for this purpose.  I want to learn how to use them

Comment: @jdharrison - I'm leaning toward recursion in `cb[[1:3]]`, but you can't do that.  But there are other things like `cb[[1,exact=TRUE]]` and `cb[[1,1,exact=TRUE]]` and `cb[[c(1,2)]]` that might be of interest.

Comment: Why recursion? You have one level of nesting here. Is there a better example where recursion required? Where the level of nested elements is known?

Comment: Well I want to go down and across at the same time. I don't know the technical terminology, but I thought it was recursion.

Comment: Now that I look further into it, I may need to use an `expression`

Comment: What about defining a recursive function? `resize.recursive <- function(cb, len = 4) if (length(cb) == 0) NULL else c("length<-"(cb[[1]], len), Recall(cb[-1, , drop = FALSE], len))`

Comment: @flodel - that looks like one very good idea, yes.  I was unaware of `Recall`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two possible ways, the first by flodel (in the comments) works very well.

```
resize.recursive <- function(x, len = 4L)
{
    if (!length(x)) NULL
    else c(`length<-`(x[[1]], len), 
           Recall(x[-1, , drop = FALSE], len))
}

resize.recursive(cb)
# [1] "apples"  "and"     "pears"   NA        "one"     "banana"  NA       
# [8] NA        "pears"   "oranges" "and"     "pizza"
```

And on this one I bit the bullet on the looping and went with `lapply`

```
replaceLength <- function(x, lev, len = 4L) `length<-`(x[[lev]], len)
unlist(lapply(1:3, replaceLength, x = cb))
# [1] "apples"  "and"     "pears"   NA        "one"    "banana"  NA 
# [8] NA        "pears"   "oranges" "and"     "pizza"
```

which is the same as

```
unlist(lapply(cb, `length<-`, 4L))
# [1] "apples"  "and"     "pears"   NA        "one"     "banana"  NA       
# [8] NA        "pears"   "oranges" "and"     "pizza"
```

I'm still open for other possibilities!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I'd give it a try:

```
    eval(parse(text=paste(sep="","c(",paste(sep="","cb[[",1:length(cb),"]][1:4]",collapse=","),")")))

    [1] "apples"  "and"     "pears"   NA        "one"     "banana"  NA       
    [8] NA        "pears"   "oranges" "and"     "pizza"
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but `eval(parse(text=...))` can have problems and its use is not recommended.

Comment: What kind of problems can have?

Comment: Well a small example would be `x <- paste(letters[1], 5, sep = "\'"); eval(parse(text = x))`. `eval` goes with `call` (and others), and `parse` goes with `deparse`.

Comment: Of course it will have problems if you have syntax errors in your text. But I don't think that `eval(parse())` may have unpredictable behaviour. If that were the case, how could you possibly `source` a file?

Comment: Did you look  at `x`?  There are no syntax errors there.

Comment: Yes, it's `a'5`. What has it supposed to mean? What did you expect the parser to do?

Comment: The point is that it didn't evaluate when we called `parse` on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60587/discussion-between-nicola-and-richard-scriven).

Comment: That's a bad example on my part, but it shouldn't be done. I can't think of an example right now but it happened to me the other day.

Comment: Can you point to a resource that explain why it shouldn't be done? I'm curious, since I've used it many times without any problem. My guess at this stage is that you didn't use it properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse A few of the people answering this question are contributors and write package that we all use

Comment: Thank you. The fact is that it is almost always a sub-obtimal (often poor) solution. In this case, for instance, it is certainly worse than lapply(cb,`length<-`,4), but I thought that you didn't want to use *apply and so I proposed this. Anyway, there aren't "hidden dangers" in the use of eval(parse()), at least no more than sourcing a file, if you do things properly.