# Using string as object in R

Tags: r, string, loops

I have variable `a` as string:

```
a = "jul_0_baseline,jul_1_baseline,...jul_11_baseline,jul_12_baseline"
```

When I try to merge the following zoo series to one table using:

```
temp <- merge(jul_0_baseline,jul_1_baseline,...jul_11_baseline,jul_12_baseline)
```

it works, however when I try to merge it using

```
temp <- merge(a)
```

I get an error as it the variable `a` is a string (even though the text is correct). I am assuming that it is effectively inputting

```
temp <- merge("jul_0_baseline,jul_1_baseline,...jul_11_baseline,jul_12_baseline")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

`a` is a string because it is created using the code:

```
a <- paste("jul","0","baseline",sep = "_")
    for (d in 1:12){ b <- paste("jul",d,"baseline",sep = "_")
                     a <- paste(a,b, sep=",")
                   }
```

Comment: Please post reproducible example.

Comment: The standard way of doing something like this is to put all the objects you want to merge in a list and using `do.call(merge,your_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since each `jul_i_baseline` listed in the string `a` corresponds to an actual object, you can do this:

```
temp <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), mget(strsplit(a, ",")[[1]]))
```

The `strsplit()` function splits `a` into a vector of strings where each element is `"jul_i_baseline"`. It returns a one-element list, so we can use `[[1]]` to get the vector of strings.

`mget()` interprets the list of variables in strings as objects. It returns a list where each element corresponds to the object. So each element is the actual Zoo object `jul_i_baseline`.

`Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), <list>)` merges the objects stored in each element of the list. Assuming the objects have a common variable on which you want to merge, you can also add a by variable in `merge()`.

---

An alternate approach as suggested in the comments is to use `do.call()` which would work since you're dealing with Zoo objects. (The former approach works with non-Zoo objects as well but this does not.) The command would be structured like so:

```
temp <- do.call(merge, mget(strsplit(c, ",")[[1]]))
```

Again we're getting the objects using `mget()` and `strsplit()`.

---

@G.Grothendiek's suggestion of using `eval(parse(...))` also works in this situation. However, many R users discourage the use of `eval(parse(...))` in general. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse).

Answer (score 0):

Form the entire command string (including `merge`) and then parse and evaluate it:

```
eval(parse(text = sprintf("merge(%s)", a)))
```