# How to generalize union() to take N arguments?

Tags: r, union, variadic-functions, generalization

How can I append/ push data into `union` dynamically?

For instance, I have 4 data sets to merge,

```
mydata <- union(data1, data2, data3, data4)
```

But sometimes I have less than 4 while sometimes more than that.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is this `union` function? The `base::union` only takes 2 vectors as input.

Comment: @Pascal I think he used it to illustrate his problem.

Comment: What? He wants to generalize `union()` to N-arguments, moreover where N changes dynamically. The 'dynamic' part is a red-herring.

Comment: Wherever the `data[0-9]...` are coming from, since their length is unknown, why not just pass in a list-of-datasets? Then for a length-N list, we only need ceil(log2(N)) `union()` calls.

Comment: @smci I get [your point about dynamic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13650955/680068), I am not going to question the "why" he is doing this way. Still an interesting question.

Comment: @smci `why not just pass in a list-of-datasets? Then for a length-N list, we only need ceil(log2(N)) union() calls.` it would be helpful if you can show me some example codes - I just started coding in R a couple of weeks ago...

Comment: @teelou: I don't understand how your code can (or should) be generating a varying number of datasets in the first place. Instead of generating distinct datasets, let's create and append to a list-of-datasets. Better still, can we do away with the individual datasets and add them to the union immediately when they are created?

Answer (score 4):

Make some reproducible data:

```
#dummy data
data1 <- data.frame(x=letters[1:3])
data2 <- data.frame(x=letters[2:4])
data3 <- data.frame(x=letters[5:7])
```

We can use `rbind` with `unique` in a string then evaluate:

```
#get list of data frames to merge, update pattern as needed
data_names <- ls()[grepl("data\\d",ls())]
data_names <- paste(data_names,collapse=",")

#make command string
myUnion <- paste0("unique(rbind(",data_names,"))")

#evaluate
eval(parse(text=myUnion))
```

**EDIT:**

Here is another *better/simpler* way, using `do.call`:

```
unique(do.call("rbind",lapply(objects(pattern="data\\d"),get)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could roll your own function like `vunion` defined below. Not sure if this actually works, my [R] got a bit stale ;)

Basically, you accept any number of arguments (hence `...`) and make use of those as if they were packed in a list. Just choose and remove the first 2 items from that list, calculate their union, append them to the list, repeat.

```
vunion <- function(...){
  data <- list(...)
  n <- length(data)
  if(n > 2){
    u <- list(t(union(data[[1]], data[[2]])))
    return(do.call(vunion, as.list(c(tail(data, -2), u))))
  } else {
    return(union(data[[1]], data[[2]]))
  }
}
```