# Use a string as a condition in If- else

Tags: r, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a variable which is
`count_process = "time>=20"`
Now i want to use it in a IF condition like

```
if(time>=20){ do something }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.  Perhaps you need `eval(parse(text=count_process))`

Comment: if i understand you right `if(count_process =="time>=20"){ do something }`

Comment: This feels like a place for code injection. Highly not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to extract the numeric substring with `sub` and use it in the `if` condition

```
 val <- as.numeric(sub('[^0-9]+', '', count_process))
 if(time >= val){do something}
```

Other option would be using `eval(parse(` (not recommended though)

```
 if(eval(parse(text=count_process))){do something}
```

Comment: Any reason/source for chiding `eval(parse(`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico  May be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) and the links inside it helps