# How do I convert a subsetted object character string name to a usable object in R?

Tags: r, string, get, subset

Suppose I have a character string of a subsetted object name. For example:

```
foo$var1[foo$var2 < 10 & foo$var3 %in% c(0:100)]  #is currently represented as...
"foo$var1[foo$var2 < 10 & foo$var3 %in% c(0:100)]"
```

I want to call the subsetted object using the character string of the object's name.

I tried using `get()`:

```
get("foo$var1[foo$var2 < 10 & foo$var3 %in% c(0:100)]")
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in "foo$var1[foo$var2 < 10 & foo$var3 %in% c(0:100)]":
object  "foo$var1[foo$var2 < 10 & foo$var3 %in% c(0:100)]" not found
```

I'm assuming there is a way to do this using subsetted objects (vs. just an object name, which I know works).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you get yourself in this situation? Putting R code into strings isn't something one might consider a good strategy in R. The `get()` functions returns variables of a given name, it does not evaluate code (and operations like `[` and `&` and `<` are functions in R). You might be able to parse and eval, `eval(parse(text=x))`, but that's not something I would recommend necessarily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @MrFlick, you can do this:

```
eval(parse(text="foo$var1[foo$var2 < 10 & foo$var3 %in% c(0:100)]"))
```

`parse` turns the string into an `expression` and `eval` evaluates that `expression`.

**Though, this is commonly considered a bad practice in R see** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(106)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for editing! I should have read the comments more carefully.