# R - as.formula() not working with ctree {party}?

Tags: r, party

I get `Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class` when I try to run a `ctree` from the `party package`, but only when the formula is writen as a string that I transform using `as.formula()`.

Below the example :

```
#This works fine :
y <- ctree(formula = quotation ~ minute + temp, data=test[[1]], controls = ctree_control(mincriterion = 0.99))

#While this doesn't :
x <- "ctree(formula = quotation ~ minute + temp, data=test[[1]], controls = ctree_control(mincriterion = 0.99))"

y <- as.formula(x)
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

My ultimate purpose is to create a function that iterates through the list `test` to create multiple trees.

Any idea ?

Comment: The `as.formula` only applies to the formula part. So it should be `x <- as.formula(quotation ~ minute + temp)`; and the line after `y <- ctree(formula=x, ...)`. For example if I use iris data set, it would be: `x1 <- as.formula(Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width);y1 <- ctree(formula = x1, data=iris)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how is `ctree` considered if not as a formula ?
I need to iterate outside of the scope of what you described as x.

Comment: I would recommend you check out the `caret` package. It has `train` function with  `tuneGrid` argument which sounds like what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctree` is a function and not a formula. `formula` is the class of the object resulting from the function `'~'` (tilde). You can learn more about formulas from `help('~')` and `help('formula')`.

The most common way to use `as.formula` is to convert a string that represents the formula syntax to an object of class formula. Something like `as.formula('y ~ x')`. Also, check `class(as.formula(y~x))`.

In your case you saved a string representing function `ctree` to variable x. Function `ctree` only contains a string representing a formula syntax (`quotation ~ minute + temp`) but it cannot be coerced to formula (it does not represent a formula, it just contains a formula syntax string) because it does not follow the formula syntax.

If you want to execute a function from text you need to use `eval(parse(text = x))` although this technique is not encouraged..

Comment: This works great thanks !
May I ask why it is not recommended ?

Comment: @YohanObadia You are very welcome. Glad I could be of help. Sure, the three main reasons are: 1. It is much slower than running the actual command, 2. It makes it much harder to read the code, and 3. It is a common source of errors when you use it in a package as in many occasions people might misspell the string. There is a discussion about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) if you want to have a look. Personally, I agree more with the second most upvoted answer.

Comment: The link was interesting. The lack of R knowledge is something I am currently facing, and beside of eval(parse()) I don't see any way to do what I want for now.