# Dynamically creating named list in R

Tags: r, list

I need to create named lists dynamically in R as follows.

Suppose there is an array of names.

```
name_arr<-c("a","b")
```

And that there is an array of values.

```
value_arr<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
list(name_arr[1]=value_arr[1:3])
```

But R throws an error when I try to do this. Any suggestions as to how to get around this problem?

Comment: `setNames(list(value_arr[1:3]), name_arr[1])`?

Comment: expanding on @docendodiscimus's comment: `setNames(list(value_arr[1:3], value_arr[4:6]), list(name_arr[1], name_arr[2]))`

Comment: @Jaap, that could be done easier with the second example in my answer

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanx! sometimes you forget the easy solutions ;-) +1

Comment: Thanks a lot! will do accordingly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `setNames`. Examples:

```
setNames(list(value_arr[1:3]), name_arr[1])
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3

setNames(list(value_arr[1:3], value_arr[4:6]), name_arr)
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$b
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Or without `setNames`:

```
mylist <- list(value_arr[1:3])
names(mylist) <- name_arr[1]
mylist
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3

mylist <- list(value_arr[1:3], value_arr[4:6])
names(mylist) <- name_arr
mylist
#$a
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$b
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 9):

you can use `[[...]]` to assign values to keys given by strings:

```
my.list <- list()
my.list[[name_arr[1]]] <- value_arr[1:3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will throw a error. Because in list(A = B), A must be a name instead of an object.

You could convert a object to a name by function eval. Here is the example.

```
eval(parse(text = sprintf('list(%s = value_arr[1:3])',name_arr[1])))
```

Comment: The `eval(parse(` daemon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse