# R & Python: How to use a string to reach into a dataframe/matrix in R

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am currently using Python and R together (using rmagic/rpy2) to help select different user input variables for a certain type of analysis.

I have read a csv file and created a dataframe in R. What I have also done is allowed the users to input a number of variables of which the names must match those in the header (using Python).

For example if I create a data frame as such

`%R data1 <- read.csv(filename, header =T)`

I then have a number of user input variables that are currently strings in pythons that would look like this.

```
var_1 = 'data1$age'
var_2 = 'data1$sex'
```

How can I then use this string as runable code in R to reach into the correct column of the data frame as such:

```
%R variable1 <- data1$sex
```

Currently I have tried the assign function and others (I understand this might be far from the mark) but I always just get it coming out as such:

```
%R -i var_1  assign('variable1', var_1)   
%R print(variable1)

"data1$age"
```

I understand that I could assign values etc in R but I'm questioning if it is possible to turn a string into a runnable bit of code that could reach into a data.frame.

Comment: [Hadley's chapter on non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) is overkill for the problem at hand, but useful to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Consider having Python call the R script as child process via command line passing the string variables as arguments. In R, use the double bracket column reference to use strings:

**Python** Script *(using subprocess module)*

```
import subprocess

var_1 = 'age' 
var_2 = 'sex'
Rfilename = '/path/to/SomeScript.R'

# BELOW ASSUMES RScript IS A SYSTEM PATH VARIABLE
p = subprocess.Popen(['RScript', Rfilename, var1, var2])
```

**R** Script

```
args <-commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)
var_1 <- as.character(args[1])
var_2 <- as.character(args[2])

data1 <- read.csv(filename, header =T)
variable1 <- data1[[var_1]]
variable2 <- data1[[var_2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```
var_1 <- "head(iris$Species)"
eval(parse(text=var_1))
# [1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Comment: @tbaker  please avoid "thankyouabsolutelyperfect" comment and accept the answer instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse