# How to perform arithmetic on values and operators expressed as strings?

Tags: r

I have a `character` variable with ratios (proportions) expressed as strings:

`x <- c("2/3", "5/6", "3/11")`.

I want to convert the character values in x into percentages. Thus, my desired output would be:

```
c(2/3, 5/6, 3/11) * 100
# [1] 66.66667 83.33333 27.27273
```

When I try the `as.numeric(x)`, a warning message is generated (NAs introduced by coercion) and all elements are converted into `NA`

What to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) read.table** Read the text in as if it were a file and then divide:

```
with(read.table(text = x, sep = "/"), 100 * V1 / V2)
## [1] 66.66667 83.33333 27.27273
```

**2) eval/parse** eval/parse is generally frowned upon but here is how it would work:

```
100 * sapply(as.list(parse(text = x)), eval)
## [1] 66.66667 83.33333 27.27273
```

**3) strsplit**

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "/"), function(x) { x <- as.numeric(x); 100 * x[1] / x[2]})
## [1] 66.66667 83.33333 27.27273
```

**4) gsubfn::strapply**  This picks out the two strings of digits using `strapply` and then converts each to numeric and divides:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(x, "(\\d+)/(\\d+)", ~ 100 * as.numeric(x) / as.numeric(y), simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 66.66667 83.33333 27.27273
```

Comment: for people like me who should wonder why `eval(parse(` is frowned upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse

Answer (score 2):

**tidyerse**

If you stumbled onto this post in search of a tidyverse answer here is a simple extension. Note this does use the aforementioned "frowned upon" `eval( parse())`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# add into a tibble
df <- tibble(fractions = c("2/3", "5/6", "3/11"))
df %>% 
  mutate(numbers = map_dbl(fractions, ~eval(parse(text = .x))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   fractions numbers
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 2/3         0.667
#> 2 5/6         0.833
#> 3 3/11        0.273
```