# Using eval parse text to read a formula to calculate value in a column

Tags: r

For the below dataframe AB, the formula values i.e. b,c,d,e,f,z,x,y etc. are in a different dataframe lets say DF.

I wish to fill the values for each item based on corresponding formula. Using eval(parse) didn't work

Here is what I had

```
AB$Value<-eval(parse(text="c+d-2"),DF)

   Item  Value  Formula 
    A      -      c+d-2 
    B      -      x+b-2 
    C      -      z+y-2 
    D      -      e+f

DF

Code     Value 
b       1
c       5
d       6
e       9
f       13
x       15
y       20
z        2
```

How do I iterate so that all values get filled based on corresponding formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parse` the column, coerce it to a list and `sapply` the `eval` across it (as in the second solution of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073503/in-r-how-to-convert-character-values-such-as-2-3-5-6-3-11-into-percenta/36073589#36073589)) :

```
L <- with(DF, as.list(setNames(Value, Code)))
transform(AB, Value = sapply(as.list(parse(text = Formula)), eval, L))
```

giving:

```
  Item Value Formula
1    A     9   c+d-2
2    B    14   x+b-2
3    C    20   z+y-2
4    D    22     e+f
```

**Note:** We used these inputs:

```
Lines <- "Item  Value  Formula 
A      -      c+d-2 
B      -      x+b-2 
C      -      z+y-2 
D      -      e+f"
AB <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "Code     Value 
b       1
c       5
d       6
e       9
f       13
x       15
y       20
z        2"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to have worked except that the empty column "Value" that I already have in my dataframe doesn't get populated and a fresh "Value" column gets created.

Comment: Presumably your setup differs in some way you haven't explained.  The code and inputs above are all reproducible and do not result in a new additional `Value` column on my machine as can be seen by the output which is shown.

Comment: Thanks - I think I figured it out. For some reason the "Value" header wasn't being picked up appropriately