# mutate in data frames list in loop

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, dplyr

I created a  list of data frames.
I'm trying to change the original data frames with **mutate** and **select** commands. I created a list from all my data frames

```
m <- as.list(paste0(rep("traffic_", 12), 2005:2016))
```

I Tried to run the next command: but it still doesn't work for me.

```
foreach(x=iter(m)) %do% { assign(x, mutate(x , date = make_datetime(shana, hodesh, taarich, shaa)) %>%
                               select( -shana, -hodesh, -taarich, -shaa)) }
```

this is one of  the original data frames

```
> traffic_2016
  shana kvish keta maslul hodesh taarich yom shaa nefah status
1      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    0  1710     NA
2      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    1   934     NA
3      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    2   800     NA
4      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    3   637     NA
5      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    4   588     NA
6      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    5   951     NA
7      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    6  2312     NA
8      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    7  3769     NA
9      2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    8  3348     NA
10     2016     1   10      1      9      11   1    9  2788     NA
11     2016     1   10      1      9      11   1   10  2879     NA
```

Comment: A mutation in the dplyr context isn't a mutation in the sense of memory modification in place.  In this context, it is a transformation.  You'll have to assign the result of your transformation to an object, so try `m[[i]] = mutate(i , date = ...`.

Comment: Try to design a function and use `lapply` to apply it to your list. It could be more efficient.

Comment: You also probably want to make your `m` object this way: `m = list(noquote(paste0(rep("traffic_", 12), 2005:2016)))` instead of writing all those traffic words.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide reproducible example dataset, and show the code to load `dplyr` and `lubridate` packages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208873/r-referencing-different-dataframes-in-a-loop/44209590#44209590 hope the link will help

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work

Comment: @MichaelSpector if my answer helped solve your issue please consider accepting it as an answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of my answer. This lets the community know the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to edit each of the original data frames:

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars
mtcars2 <- mtcars

m <- list("mtcars1","mtcars2")
```

You can use `assign` to edit data by name. I use `get` to edit the actual data:

```
library(iterators)
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)
foreach(x=iter(m)) %do% { assign(x, mutate(get(x), mpg=mpg+1) %>% select(mpg,cyl)) }
```

Using your `mutate`:

```
foreach(x=iter(m)) %do% { assign(x, mutate(get(x) , date = make_datetime(shana, hodesh, taarich, shaa)) %>% select( -shana, -hodesh, -taarich, -shaa)) }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. It writes error:  Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"lapply(iter(m), function(X) mutate(x, date = make_datetime(shana, hodesh, taarich, shaa))
5"

Comment: Double check that your `mutate` and `select` work on each data frame. Looks like one of your data frames might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, It works but the values still remain as before. for example when I print the 'Traffic_2015" it still the same as before. how can save the data frames according to the lapply function ?

Comment: Looks like you should edit your original post. You saved your `df` in a `list`, but this does not reference the original `df`. You want to save only the names of `df` in a list, and update each `df` by name using `assign`.

Comment: so how can I do it, how can I change the original data ?

Comment: Edited my post for what you actually want. Edit your original post still...

Comment: It write me an error:   Error in { : task 1 failed - "invalid first argument""

Comment: sorry, I forgot to upload the relevant libraries , but it still make an error

Comment: it write 'Error in { : task 1 failed - "invalid first argument"'

Comment: Can you update your post with what you've tried....as I asked you to do twice before. My guess is you didn't update your `m` to a list of characters...but I can't be sure.

Comment: how can change the type of the list ?

Comment: `m <- as.list(paste0(rep("traffic_", 12), 2005:2016))`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. thanks a lot, but it still doesn't work it write me an error: Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character""

Comment: Change `mutate(x)` to `mutate(get(x)`

Comment: Thanks. It did well :) , I still curios to know what this command "get" did ?