# Create a data.frame using a string expression in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

How can I create a data frame from the following string:

```
my_str <- "a=1, b=2"
```

In other words, how can I feed y into the data.frame or data.table functions so that it gives me the same thing as

```
data.frame(a=1, b=2)
```

Think about how you can easily pass a string of form `my_str <- "y~x1+x2+x3"` into a statistical model in R by simply using `as.formula(my_str)` and effectively remove the quotes. So I am looking for a similar solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly discourage you from storing code as a string in R. There are almost always better ways to write R code that don't require parsing strings.

But let's assume you have no other options. Then you can write your own parser, or use R's built in parser. The expression "a=1, b=2" on it's own doesn't make any sense in R (you can't have two "assignments" separated by a comma) so it would only make sense as parameters to a function.

If you want to wrap it in `data.frame()`, then you can use `paste()` to make the string you want and then `parse()` and finally `eval()` it to run it

```
my_str <- "a=1, b=2"
my_code <- paste0("data.frame(", my_str, ")")
my_expr <- parse(text=my_code)
eval(my_expr)
#   a b
# 1 1 2
```

But like I already mentioned [eval/parse should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse).