# lazy evaluation in R

Tags: r, lazy-loading

I have the following code in R:

```
named_list = list()
for (i in 1:5){
named_list[[i]] = function(one,two){c(one,two, i)}
}
```

However, when I call the function:

```
> named_list[[1]]("first", "second")
[1] "first"  "second" "5"
```

Is there a way to get this to work properly (to return "first", "second", "1") without using the apply functions?  I have tried to use the force function as recommended in another thread, but I cannot get it to work.

Thanks.

Edit: For some clarification, I am looking to make a list of functions, each of which encloses the index of where that function is in that list.  In particular, observe that

```
> named_list[[1]]("first", "second")
[1] "first"  "second" "5"

> named_list[[2]]("first", "second")
[1] "first"  "second" "5"

> named_list[[3]]("first", "second")
[1] "first"  "second" "5"

> named_list[[4]]("first", "second")
[1] "first"  "second" "5"

> named_list[[5]]("first", "second")
[1] "first"  "second" "5"
```

which is obviously not the desired behaviour.  The problem is that looping i through 1 to 5, R sees the first 'i' indexing the named_list, but doesn't see the second 'i' which is inside the function I am trying to define.

I am aware that the following is a possible solution (although I do not know *why* it works):

```
named_list = lapply(1:5, function(i) function(one,two)(c(one,two,i)))
```

but I want to know if there is an alternative solution that uses the for loop.

Comment: Why is this "lazy evaluation"? Is there a reason you cannot define `named_list<-function(one,two,i=1)`; or perhaps `nl<-function(i){function(one,two)...}` and use `named_list(1)(one,two)`? I guess I don't understand (1) the intent of your list of functions; (2) your aversion to `*apply`; and (3) your aversion to a more classical function definition.

Comment: Please see my edit, which I hope clarifies some of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is related to *scope* or *namespace*. Namely, when in a function and a variable is referenced that has not been defined locally in that function, R starts searching in the parent "frame" (environment where its variables are defined); if not there, then it goes to the parent's parent frame (grand-parent frame?); etc. (One good read for this is [Advanced R: Environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html); an extra read might be the same book's chapter on [Memory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html).)

It's helpful to look at the `environment` being used/searched at any given time. I'll focus on the current, parent, and when inside the function, the "grand-parent" environments; realize, though, that deeply nested functions may have many more (which suggests you need to be very careful when depending on R to hunt-down and find the specific instance of a variable not in the local environment!).

NB: you will very likely not get the same `<environment: 0x000...>` pointers. These references are completely unreproducible and change each time this code is run.

---

Let's start with the `lapply` setup *that works*:

```
print(environment())
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
nl1 <- lapply(1:2, function(i) {
  e1 <- environment()
  str(list(where="inside lapply", env=e1, parent=parent.env(e1)))
  function(one,two) {
    e2 <- environment()
    str(list(where="inside func", env=e2, parent=parent.env(e2),
             grandparent=parent.env(parent.env(e2))))
    c(one, two, i)
  }
})
# List of 3
#  $ where : chr "inside lapply"
#  $ env   :<environment: 0x0000000009128fe0> 
#  $ parent:<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
# List of 3
#  $ where : chr "inside lapply"
#  $ env   :<environment: 0x00000000090bb578> 
#  $ parent:<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

First notice that with each iteration within `lapply`, there is a new environment, starting with `9128fe0`, whose parent is the global env. Within the second iteration of the `lapply`, we are in `90bb578`, and within that environment, we define the `function(one,two)` whose local environment is `8f811b8` (which we see in the next code block).

Realize that at this time, R has not attempted to resolve `i`. Let's run a function:

```
nl1[[2]](11,12)
# List of 4
#  $ where      : chr "inside func"
#  $ env        :<environment: 0x0000000008f811b8> 
#  $ parent     :<environment: 0x00000000090bb578> 
#  $ grandparent:<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
# [1] 11 12  2
```

So when we reference `i`, R searches in the following, in order, to find it:

- `8f811b8`: inside `function(one,two)...`, not found
- `90bb578`: immediate parent env, inside `function(i) ...`; **found**
- `R_GlobalEnv` (not searched, since it was found previously)

---

Okay, let's try the `for` loop:

```
nl2 <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
  e1 <- environment()
  str(list(where="inside for", env=e1, parent=parent.env(e1)))
  nl2[[i]] <- function(one,two) {
    e2 <- environment()
    str(list(where="inside func", env=e2, parent=parent.env(e2),
             grandparent=parent.env(parent.env(e2))))
    c(one, two, i)
  }
}
# List of 3
#  $ where : chr "inside for"
#  $ env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ parent:<environment: package:tcltk> 
#   ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "package:tcltk"
#   ..- attr(*, "path")= chr "c:/R/R-3.3.3/library/tcltk"
# List of 3
#  $ where : chr "inside for"
#  $ env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ parent:<environment: package:tcltk> 
#   ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "package:tcltk"
#   ..- attr(*, "path")= chr "c:/R/R-3.3.3/library/tcltk"
```

First thing to notice is that within each iteration of the `for` loop, the local environment is `R_GlobalEnv`, which should make sense. (You can safely ignore the reference to the `tcltk` environment as the parent.)

Okay, now when we get to the `nl2[[1]]` call, notice that the parent environment is (perhaps now, not surprisingly) the `R_GlobalEnv` environment:

```
nl2[[1]](11,12)
# List of 4
#  $ where      : chr "inside func"
#  $ env        :<environment: 0x000000001b1a6720> 
#  $ parent     :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ grandparent:<environment: package:tcltk> 
#   ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "package:tcltk"
#   ..- attr(*, "path")= chr "c:/R/R-3.3.3/library/tcltk"
# [1] 11 12  2
```

This was the first time that R needed to *find* `i`, so it first searched within `1b1a6720` (within `function(one,two)`, where it was not found), and then in the `R_GlobalEnv`.

**So why did it return "2"?**

Because the value of `i` in `R_GlobalEnv` is, at the time we called `nl2[[2]]`, the last value of `i` in the `for` loop. See this:

```
rm(i)
for (i in 1:100) { } # no-op
i
# [1] 100
```

What's even more telling is if we try to call the function now:

```
nl2[[1]](11,12)
# List of 4
#  $ where      : chr "inside func"
#  $ env        :<environment: 0x000000000712c2a0> 
#  $ parent     :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ grandparent:<environment: package:tcltk> 
#   ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "package:tcltk"
#   ..- attr(*, "path")= chr "c:/R/R-3.3.3/library/tcltk"
# [1]  11  12 100
```

So the evaluation of `i` within that function is lazy in that it searches when you call the function.

In your environment (before you change any code), if you typed in `i <- 100`, you would see similar behavior.

---

If you are absolutely against using `lapply` (which is my preferred method here, even if I don't understand your underlying need here), try explicitly defining the environment that surrounds your function. One way is to use [`local`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html), which will preserve searching within existing parent environments while allowing us to "force" which `i` we want used. (Other options exist, I invite others to comment and for you to explore environments more.)

```
nl3 <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
  e1 <- environment()
  str(list(where="inside for", env=e1, parent=parent.env(e1)))
  nl3[[i]] <- local({
    i <- i # forces it locally within this env
    function(one,two) {
      e2 <- environment()
      str(list(where="inside func", env=e2, parent=parent.env(e2),
               grandparent=parent.env(parent.env(e2))))
      c(one, two, i)
    }
  })
}
# List of 3
#  $ where : chr "inside for"
#  $ env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ parent:<environment: package:tcltk> 
#   ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "package:tcltk"
#   ..- attr(*, "path")= chr "c:/R/R-3.3.3/library/tcltk"
# List of 3
#  $ where : chr "inside for"
#  $ env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
#  $ parent:<environment: package:tcltk> 
#   ..- attr(*, "name")= chr "package:tcltk"
#   ..- attr(*, "path")= chr "c:/R/R-3.3.3/library/tcltk"
nl3[[1]](11,12)
# List of 4
#  $ where      : chr "inside func"
#  $ env        :<environment: 0x0000000019ca23e0> 
#  $ parent     :<environment: 0x000000001aabe388> 
#  $ grandparent:<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
# [1] 11 12  1
i <- 1000
nl3[[1]](11,12)
# List of 4
#  $ where      : chr "inside func"
#  $ env        :<environment: 0x0000000008d0bc78> 
#  $ parent     :<environment: 0x000000001aabe388> 
#  $ grandparent:<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
# [1] 11 12  1
```

(You may notice that the local environment when you call the function changes each time while the parent does not. This is because when you call a function, it starts at the beginning of the function's call with a new environment. You "know" and rely on this because you assume that at the beginning of your function, no variables are defined. This is normal.)

Comment: Hey, not the original poster, but wanted to say great explanation! Could you elaborate on how the `local` function actually works? Does it act such that any script inside the `local` function will only look for variables inside those brackets? If so, how is it that `i <- i` will take the parent `i` and place it inside the local `i`?

Comment: It doesn't block scope search (try `local({ parent.env(environment()) })` to see that it reaches out), but it's a way to place specific *things* (variables, functions) into a manually-defined environment. The use of `i<-...` ensures there is a variable named "i" in the `local` environment; the fact that I set it to the value of `i` in the enclosing environment is coincidental. Now, technically, there are two such `i` objects, one in the `local` env, one in global, but the functions should always find the former one first.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. A  LOT of sense actually. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I get into situations like this I decide to just write it out as text and wrap it inside an eval statement. Like so.

```
named_list = list()
for (i in 1:5){

  eval(parse(text = paste0("named_list[[i]] = function(one,two){c(one,two,", i, ")}")))

}

named_list[[1]]("first", "second")
```

Now I get

```
> named_list[[1]]("first", "second")
[1] "first"  "second" "1"
```

As desired.

So all I did was make what I know I wanted to string to be in text and get it to evaluate it that way instead.

There's probably a better solution, but that will do the job for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse

Comment: I agree! It depends on context though, sometimes I use R a lot for experimentation. Often this is faster than working out the 'other' way to do things. If my code ever becomes something where speed is needed, that's when I jump out of the eval(parse()) world. I think it's a good get the job done tool, but as I say, there's probably a better solution :)