# Add Ggplot Output to in Nested For Loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have this nested for loop where for each site and species combination it runs a GAM model on count vs time (n ~ s(unix)). I am struggling to get the ggplot outputs to save in the final list. Currently it only overwrites the last site and species combination. The code works with out issues when just looping through species and save the ggplots in a list. However when I added the outside loop and follow the same process the last site and set of species gets overwritten.

I know the loop is working properly because if I change the p<- to print() in the ggplot section all the figure are printed.

Any help as to the most likely minor change I need to make for the site and species combinations do not over write the last empty ggplot list?

Dput and code are below

#### Code

```
if (!require(librarian)){
  install.packages("librarian")
  library(librarian)
}

librarian::shelf(tidyverse, RPostgres, DBI, here, lubridate, unmarked, mgcv, voxel, data.table)


# Create empty objects
species_list <- unique(clean_cap$species_capture)

plots <- list()

all_plots <- list()


site_list <- unique(clean_cap$site)

# Loop for site
for (j in 1:length(site_list)){

# Loop through each species
    for (i in 1:length(species_list)) {
      
      # find species with low k value
      k <- clean_cap %>% 
        filter(species_capture == species_list[i],
               site == site_list[j]) %>%
        mutate(year_month = as_date(date, format = "%Y-%m"),
               year_month = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(year_month, format = "%Y-%m")),
               year_month = sort(year_month)) %>%  
        select(year_month) %>% 
        unique() %>% 
        nrow()
      
      # only run models for species with k>8
      if (k > 9) {

          
          # filter clean data set for species list of k>8
          dat <- clean_cap %>% 
            select(species_capture, date, n, site) %>% 
            filter(species_capture == species_list[i],
                   site == site_list[j]) %>%  
            ungroup() %>% 
            select(!species_capture, site) %>% 
            mutate(unix = as_date(date, format = "%Y-%m"),
                   unix = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(unix, format = "%Y-%m")),
                   unix = sort(unix)) 
    
      
          # run GAM per species
          gam <- gam(n ~ s(unix, k = k), data = dat) 
          
          # create new object in environment for each model output per species
          #assign(paste(site_list[j], "_",species_list[i], sep = ""), gam) 
          
          # Predictions
          unix = seq(min(dat$unix), max(dat$unix), len=100)
          newdata = data.frame(unix=unix)
          gam_pred = predict(gam, newdata=newdata, type="response", se.fit = T)
          newdata$pred = gam_pred$fit
          newdata$upper_se <- gam_pred$fit + (2 * gam_pred$se.fit)
          newdata$lower_se <- gam_pred$fit - (2 * gam_pred$se.fit)
          
          # save predictions
          #write_rds(as.data.frame(newdata), here("outputs", "abundance", "gam_unix_per_species_site", 
                                                 paste(site_list[j], "_", species_list[i],".rds", sep = "")))
          
          
          # Average prevalence for plotting
          dat = data.table(dat)
          dat[, c("month", "year"):=.(month(date), year(date))]
          average_n = dat[, .(av_n=mean(n), mean_unix=mean(unix)), by=.(month, year)] 
    
          # make GAM plot 
          # Change "p<-" to "print(ggplot info)" and all the plots will print#
           p <- ggplot(newdata) + geom_line(aes(x=unix, y=pred)) +
                                 geom_point(data=dat, aes(x=unix, y=n), size=3, alpha = 0.5) + # raw or predicted counts displayed?
                                 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_se, ymax= upper_se, x = unix), alpha = 0.2, fill = "blue")+
                                 xlab("Unix") + ylab("Abundance (Perfect Detection)") + theme_classic() +
                                 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(newdata$upper_se) + 5)) + 
                                 ggtitle(paste(site_list[j], "-", species_list[i], sep = ""))
            
            
            
            
        # save GAM plot in list
         plots[[i]] <- p
         
        
      
      }
      
      # Error checking during loop
      print(paste("done with", site_list[j], "_", species_list[i]))
    
  }
  
  ####This is not working. It is being written over for one site####
  all_plots[[j]] <- plots

}
```

#### sample data

```
clean_cap <- structure(list(site = c("rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"rv_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "rv_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", 
"rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"rv_pond", "rv_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"rv_pond", "rv_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", 
"rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", "tuttle_pond", 
"rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "tuttle_pond", "rv_pond", 
"rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", 
"rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "rv_pond", "rv_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond", 
"wood_lab_pond", "wood_lab_pond"), date = structure(c(17262, 
17263, 17285, 17285, 17296, 17296, 17296, 17297, 17297, 17311, 
17311, 17317, 17317, 17328, 17329, 17329, 17329, 17329, 17329, 
17330, 17331, 17331, 17332, 17333, 17334, 17334, 17358, 17358, 
17361, 17361, 17361, 17361, 17382, 17392, 17392, 17392, 17392, 
17393, 17393, 17417, 17417, 17417, 17418, 17418, 17621, 17643, 
17647, 17647, 17663, 17663, 17672, 17679, 17679, 17697, 17697, 
17698, 17698, 17713, 17713, 17728, 17728, 17732, 17732, 17737, 
17737, 17758, 17758, 17761, 17761, 17789, 17789, 17804, 17804, 
17819, 17819, 17824, 17992, 18038, 18038, 18066, 18066, 18074, 
18074, 18083, 18083, 18173, 18173, 18175, 18180, 18181, 18181, 
17994, 17994, 17998, 18000, 18006, 18025, 18039, 18042, 18044, 
18060, 18062, 18067, 18071, 18072, 18073, 18076, 18080, 18083, 
18088, 18093, 18094, 18114, 18115, 18116), class = "Date"), species_capture = c("lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_catesbeianus", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", 
"lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans", "lithobates_clamitans"
), n = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 15L, 6L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 9L, 22L, 4L, 3L, 11L, 25L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 
15L, 17L, 19L, 4L, 20L, 2L, 16L, 14L, 6L, 20L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 23L, 
4L, 5L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 15L, 3L, 21L, 9L, 
29L, 1L, 20L, 2L, 30L, 31L, 22L, 3L, 27L, 12L, 19L, 23L, 16L, 
22L, 3L, 9L, 13L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 29L, 6L, 6L, 
18L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 18L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 12L, 7L, 10L, 18L, 11L, 
11L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -115L))
```

### Update

Turns out this code is not broken and it was performing the desired output. My confusion was how the ggplots were nested in a list.
I was using the code below to open the list and thought I was missing data.

```
# Incorrect way to view all plots
plots[1:length(plots)]

# Correct way to view nested list of plots
unlist(all_plots, recursive = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a lazy evaluation problem.  The simplest solution is likely to involve changing your `for` loop to a member of the `apply` family.

Comment: @r2evans gives a superb explanation of what's going on with lazy evaluation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616095/lazy-evaluation-in-r). Hadley Wickham's explanation is [here](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).

Comment: @Limey yep it does seem to have to do with lazy evaluation and the need to use locla(). I will work on it

Comment: Is the update here part of the question, or is the update a summary of the answer? If the latter, it would be best to put that in a self-answer, so as to help future readers differentiate between question material and answer material.

Comment: It is part of the answer in that i was not understanding the output of the loop. I initially thought the loop had an issue but it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, the only two plots that I see that are the same are `all_plots[[2]][[2]]` and `all_plots[[3]][[2]]`. All the others are different for me. Tested with `ggplot2_3.4.2`

The problem is your check for "only run models for species with k>8". The last group doesn't have enough values. Since you only reset `plots <- list()` at the top of the loop, it doesn't set reset each iteraction, so if a group fails, it will use what ever was left over in that list from the previous iteration. Try moving `plots <- list()` into just inside the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pleased, but not surprised, that you're on the right track.

As an alternative to using, say, `lapply`, here's a skeleton of a solution using `group_map` from the tidyverse.  Group map applies a function (its argument) to each group of a grouped data frame.  (Or to the entire data frame if it's ungrouped.)

The function takes two arguments, conventionally named `.x` and `.y`.  `.x` contains the data for the current group (omitting the grouping variables by default) and `.y` is a single row data frame whose columns define the current group.

`group_map` returns a list, the elements of which is the result of applying the function to each .x in turn.

I can't replicate your code because it is not reproducible: you haven't told us which packages you're using.  [I can work out you're using `here`, and I guessed `gam`, but I don't know where `s` comes from.]  So I've simply ilustrated the technique by creating a list of plots (so you know it works!) of `n` against `date` for each combination of `site` and `species_capture`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create year_month only once, for efficiency
clean_cap <- clean_cap %>% 
  mutate(year_month = lubridate::month(date, label = FALSE))

plot_list <- clean_cap %>% 
  group_by(site, species_capture) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      # I think this is your intent...
      if (length(.x %>% distinct(year_month) %>% nrow() > 9)) {
          .x %>%
            ggplot() +
              geom_line(aes(x = date, y = n)) +
              labs(title = paste(.y$site, .y$species_capture))
      } else {
        NA
      }
    }
  )

plot_list
```

PS: This will also avoid the bug that MrFlick noted in their comment.