# R evaluate a funtion with class string

Tags: r, string, function

I have a function in string format `"dnorm(0,1)"` which I want to evaluate but I need to make a change to string first. How do I subsequently run the function from character format?

```
function_char_format = str_replace("dnorm(0,1),.,"r") %>%
str_replace(".","r") %>% 
str_replace("\\(","(1e4, ") #this returns "rnorm(100,0,1)"
execute_function??(function_char_format)
```

context:
(I'm making a function where I'm extracting a distribution like "dnorm" from an r-object and need the corresponding "rnorm()" . The solution should also be applicable for "dbinom", "dpois" etc.)

Edit: added str_replace line

Comment: What do you have and what do you expect to get? Your question is unclear. What do you want to change it to? What parameters do you need to give it?

Comment: I got `"dnorm(0,1)"` and I need output from `rnorm(100,0,1)` i.e. a list of number. (Just realized I missed a str_replace call where I add the 100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a combination of `eval(parse(text=...))` and `gsub(pattern, new_pattern, ...)`

```
S <- "dnorm(0,1)"
set.seed(1)
eval(parse(text=S))
# 0.2419707
set.seed(1)
T <- gsub("norm", "pois", S)
eval(parse(text=T))
# 0.3678794
```

Comment: It's often a good idea to accompany any mention of `eval(parse(text = ...))` with a minimal note that it is generally considered a bad idea, and should be avoided if at all possible. (Even if it's what the OP actually needs, believe me, lots of unsuspecting beginners will land on this question via Google and use it unthinkingly.)

Comment: Thanks @joran -  I wasn't aware that this was generally frowned upon.

Comment: See `fortunes::fortune(106)` and `fortunes::fortune(181)` and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649979/324364

Answer (score 2):

I actually am a fan of `parse(text = ...)`.

For example, if you have some named arguments:

```
old <- 'dnorm(x = 5, mean=1)'
cl <- parse(text = old)[[1L]]
eval(cl)
# [1] 0.0001338302

cl[[1L]] <- dlnorm
eval(cl)
# [1] 0.06626564

cl$mean <- 5
eval(cl)
# [1] 0.0002544689
```

But in your case, we can avoid `parse(text = ...)` with `do.call` or `call` since unnamed arguments can be passed by position:

```
old <- 'dnorm(0, 1)'
new <- 'rnorm'


args <- strsplit(old, '[(),]')[[1L]]
args <- lapply(args, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)

do.call(args[[1L]], args[-1L])
# [1] 0.2419707

## add more arguments like n for rnorm
set.seed(1L)
do.call(new, c(5L, args[-1L]))
# [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078

## or use a named list to pass to a specific argument
# do.call(new, c(n = 5L, args[-1L]))

## or change to another function with similar use
args[[1L]] <- 'pnorm'
cl <- do.call(call, args)
eval(cl)
# [1] 0.1586553    

cl[[1L]] <- pnorm
eval(cl)
# [1] 0.1586553
```

Statistically speaking, there are almost 400 fortunes, and only 2 of them are anti-`parse(text)`. That's pretty good..