# Get data out of "c(\"a\", \"b\")" format

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, data-cleaning, stringr

I have a string `"c(\"AV\", \"IM\")"`, which I'm trying to transform into the string `"AV IM"`.

My issue is that I can't `unlist()` or `flatten()` this, as it's a character, and neither `paste()` nor `stringr::str_c()` work, since it's technically still 1 character value.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Tidyverse solutions preferred, if possible.

EDIT: I know this can be solved via regex, but I feel like this is more a "fundamental" problem to be solved string-level than it is a regex problem, if that makes any sense.

Comment: iI you're the one responsible for getting your data in this shape (maybe using `as.character(substitute(...))` ?) you'd be better off solving this upstream.

Comment: i'm with you there. Definitely want to fix this early. The problem is I'm not really sure how. I think it's a string-level issue (not character-level, where regex makes sense).

Comment: what is the instruction that outputs this string ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how you got here, but this as presented would be an eval/parse situation. However, as noted in many other answers on this site, there's almost always a better way of preparing your data so you end up in a more R-friendly form. See, for starters, [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(...))?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13649979/210673).

```
> a <- "c(\"AV\", \"IM\")"
> (b <- eval(parse(text=a)))
[1] "AV" "IM"
> paste(b, collapse=" ")
[1] "AV IM"
```

Comment: I think here it's precisely a case where `eval(parse(text` is the cleanest solution. What is not clean is what was done to the data before to get it into this form.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant, thanks for the clarification, I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider to use regular expression to replace all symbols and the beginning c.

```
s <- "c(\"AV\", \"IM\")"

s_vec <- strsplit(s, split = ",")[[1]]

gsub("[[:punct:]]|^c", "", s_vec)
# [1] "AV"  " IM"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not quite easy how you got here. You can use eval-parse, though it is not vectorized. And also it is slow. Thus you need a regular expression:

```
 a <- "c(\"AV\", \"IM\")"
 stringr::str_extract_all(a,"\\w+(?!\\()")
[[1]]
[1] "AV" "IM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers output a vector. My understanding is you want a space-delimited list of your strings.

```
library(dplyr)

a <- "c(\"AV\", \"IM\")"

a %>%
  gsub("c(", "", ., fixed=TRUE) %>% 
  gsub("\"", "", ., fixed=TRUE) %>% 
  gsub(",",  "", ., fixed=TRUE) %>% 
  gsub(")",  "", ., fixed=TRUE)
```

Output

```
"AV IM"
```

---

EDIT Or simply (from @www's answer):

```
a %>%
  gsub("[[:punct:]]|^c",  "", .)
```