# Evaluate a value in R given either the name of a promise or the formal argument

Tags: r, function, eval, lazy-evaluation

### Code:

```
args <- function() {
  list(
    x = "How old",
    y = "is",
    z = "the car?")
}

fun1 <- function(x = "How old", y = "is", z = "the car") {
  # collect arguments
  args_used   <- as.list(match.call()[-1])

  # Call fun2() using the args supplied by the user
  do.call(fun2, args_used)

}

fun2 <- function(x = args()$x, y = args()$y, z = args()$z) {
  paste(x, y, z)
}
```

### Problem

Using `fun1()` and/or `fun2()` works if used directely, try e.g.,

```
> fun1("Where", "are", z = "the cars")
[1] "Where are the cars"
```

However, if I do:

```
list1 <- list(l1 = "Where", l2 = "Is this")
list2 <- list(l1 = "is", l2 = "the")
list3 <- list(l1 = "Peter", l2 = "new iPhone?")

mapply(function(i, j, k) fun1(x = i, y = j, z = k),
       i = list1,
       j = list2,
       k = list3,
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I get

> `Error in paste(x, y, z) : object 'i' not found`

I know *why* the problem happens and I even know how to fix it using `eval(parse(text = ""))` (although I am aware of potential problems of the eval-parse strategy (see, e.g.: [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Therefore rewriting `fun1()` like this:

```
fun1 <- function(x = "How old", y = "is", z = "the car") {
  # collect arguments
  args_used <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  args_used <- lapply(names(args_used), function(w) eval(parse(text = w))) 

  # Call fun2() using the args supplied by the user
  do.call(fun2, args_used)

}
```

and subsequently using `mapply(....)` as above works.

However here it becomes tricky.

1. Notice what happens if I change `w` in `lapply(names(args_used), function(w) eval(parse(text = w)))` to `x` (the same holds true for `y` and `z`. Now calling `mapply` as above again, give:

   > ```
   > $`l1`
   > [1] "x is Peter"
   >
   > $l2
   > [1] "x the new iPhone?"
   > ```
   >
   > Clearly not what I wanted. Again I understand why this happens and a fix would be to not use `x` but something like `w` but any name a pick is from now on reserved. Not ideal.
2. The approach also breaks if one of the arguments is called via the `...` argument. Modifying `fun1()` like this:

   ```
   fun1 <- function(x = "How old", y = "is", ...) {
     # collect arguments
     args_used <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
     args_used <- lapply(names(args_used), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))) 

     # Call fun2() using the args supplied by the user
     do.call(fun2, args_used)

   }
   ```

   now results in

   > `Error in eval(parse(text = x)) : object 'z' not found`

Again, I understand why (because the name `"z"` is unknown within the `fun1()` environement) but the question now is:

**How do I solve this issue in a way that it avoids problem 1 and problem 2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your function evaluate the parameters in the calling environment. This seems to work (note the addition of `envir=parent.frame()`).

```
fun1 <- function(x = "How old", y = "is", z = "the car") {
  args_used  <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  do.call(fun2, args_used, envir=parent.frame()) 
}
```

But I can't see why you are using lazy evaluation at all here. You can just capture all the arugments as part of the environment and pass along their values

```
fun1 <- function(x = "How old", y = "is", z = "the car") {
  args_used  <- as.list(environment())
  # if you need ...: args_used <- c(as.list(environment()), list(...))
  do.call(fun2, args_used) 
}
```

Note that the `environment()` will capture all variables that exist at the time you call it. So if you just want the variables that are passed in to your function, be sure to call it at the start of your function.

If your parameters have leading dots in their names, R normally treats these as "hidden" so you'll need to set the `all.names=TRUE` parameter to the `as.list.environment` function to get them. You can do

```
args_used  <- as.list(environment(), all.names=TRUE)
```