# Creating a single function based on multiple other functions with different parameter

Tags: r, function, loops

I have two functions with different parameters, let say function `f` and function `g`:

```
f <- function(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) {  
      w <- a1+a2+a3+a4+a5 
}
```

and

```
g <- function(x, y) { 
      z <- w*x*y 
      print(z)
}
```

I am trying to merge this two functions into one and all I can think is doing it like this:

```
m <- function(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,x,y) {
        w <- a1+a2+a3+a4+a5
        z <- w*x*y
        print(z) 
}
```

The problem with function `m` is that I find it too messy because of too much parameters.

> My goal is that to create a function that will go through  `f` first and then go through `g` and finally print the answer.

The reason that I want to do this is that, in my code there will be almost 3 to 5 functions (let say `g`,`h`,`i`,`j`,`k`) all with different parameters. However, these functions will undergo the primary function first (function `f`), and then will execute either one of `g`,`h`,`i`,`j`,`k`, based on users input. I have the idea of using loop, but I didn't know which loop to apply.

For example, I have another function `h` and `i`:

```
h <- function(b,c) { 
      t <- w*b/c 
      print(z)
}

i <- function(d, e) { 
      v <- w+d*e 
      print(z)
}
```

The thing that I wanna do is that to create a single function (maybe using loop) from all this function. Function `f` is the primary function (which means that this is the first thing to be execute) and then based on user input, it will either execute function `g`,`h`, or `i`.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want to happen here. I mean, when you assign values to variables inside functions, those variables disappear after the function exits. Functions in R should return values and not run with side effects. What are these functions really supposed to do? Maybe there's a better design for the long term.

Comment: @MrFlick I had edit some new information on my post. I hope it helps.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal of all these functions?

Comment: @NelsonGon the goal is that, user will choose the functions they prefer and input the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function `main` which accepts `g`, `x`, `y` and the `f` arguments.  The `f` arguments will be passed via `...`.  Now since `g` refers to `w` which is not defined in `g` it will look to the lexical parent of `g` for `w` so either `g` must be defined within `f` or else we must reset the environment of `g` to that within `f` so that `w` can be found when `g` is run.  We do the latter.

If it were possible to redefine `g` so that `w` is explicitly passed to it via an argument then we can remove the line that resets the environment of `g` and modify the call to `g` to add `w` in the argument list.

```
f <- function(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) {  
      w <- a1+a2+a3+a4+a5 
}

g <- function(x, y) { 
      z <- w*x*y 
      print(z)
}

h <- function(b,c) { 
      t <- w*b/c 
      print(t)
}

i <- function(d, e) { 
      v <- w+d*e 
      print(v)
}

main <- function(FUN, x, y, ...) {
  environment(FUN) <- environment()
  w <- f(...)
  FUN(x, y)
}

# tests
a1 <- a2 <- a3 <- a4 <- a5 <- x <- y <- 1

main(g, x, y, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
## [1] 5

main(h, x, y, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
## [1] 5

main(i, x, y, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)
## [1] 6
```

Comment: This seems robust. Out of curiosity, could there be a way to build something like a function factory or use such calls as `force`?

Comment: One could curry `main` like this: `library(purrr); main_g <- partial(main, FUN = g)` although note the minor bug in `partial` https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/656

Answer (score 0):

Not sure  I got the aim well but we could use:

**Edit:**

After reading about the dangers of `eval(parse())` thanks to @Maurits Evers, we could use `get` instead:

```
 combfn1<-function(x,y,func,...){
      w<-do.call(get(func),list(c(...)))
      z<-w*x*y
      print(z)
    }
   combfn1(1,2,"sum",3,4,6)
```

The dangers of the function below have been answered in several posts, one of which is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse).

```
 combfn<-function(x,y,func,...){
      w<-do.call(eval(parse(text=quote(func))),list(c(...)))
      z<-w*x*y
      print(z)
    }
    combfn(1,2,"sum",3,4)
```

Comment: Perhaps relevant here is [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(…))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse).

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers. I'll leave the answer here for historical purposes.

Answer (score -2):

What if you just put f and g inside m? Would this work? I dont have R in front of me atm.

```
m <- function(f, g) {


f <- function(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) {  
      w <- a1+a2+a3+a4+a5 
}

g <- function(x, y) { 
      z <- w*x*y 
      print(z)
}
f()
g()

}
```