# Add dynamic subset conditions as variables into the data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame like

```
> x = data.frame(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(2,3,4))
> x
  A B
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

and subsetting conditions in a data frame like

```
> cond = data.frame(condition=c('A>1','B>2 & B<4'))
> cond
  condition
1       A>1
2 B>2 & B<4
```

which I then apply dynamically

```
> eval(parse(text=paste0("subset(x,",cond[1,'condition'],")")))
  A B
2 2 3
3 3 4
> eval(parse(text=paste0("subset(x,",cond[2,'condition'],")")))
  A B
2 2 3
```

Now, instead of subsetting, I would like to add the subsetting conditions as variables into the data. The end result would look like

```
  A B condition1 condition2
1 1 2          0          0  
2 2 3          1          1
3 3 4          1          0
```

How could I derive the above table using the dynamic conditions?

Comment: `x <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(2,3,4));
condition <- c('A>1','B>2 & B<4');

with(x, sapply(condition, function(cond) eval(parse(text=cond))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using `eval` `parse`, I hope you have gone through some readings like

[What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(…))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

and many others which are available.

However, to answer your question, we can continue your flow and use `eval` `parse` in `sapply`

```
+(sapply(seq_len(nrow(cond)), function(i) 
            eval(parse(text=paste0("with(x,",cond[i,'condition'],")")))))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    1    0
```

To add it to the dataframe,

```
x[paste0("condition", 1:nrow(cond))] <- 
         +(sapply(seq_len(nrow(cond)), function(i) 
         eval(parse(text=paste0("with(x,",cond[i,'condition'],")")))))

x
#  A B condition1 condition2
#1 1 2          0          0
#2 2 3          1          1
#3 3 4          1          0
```

---

Simplifying it a bit (using @jogo's comment)

```
+(sapply(cond$condition, function(i) with(x, eval(parse(text=as.character(i))))))

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    1    0
```

Comment: Yes, read those warnings on using `eval`and `parse`. I am reusing the conditions in several places, therefore they are in a table.

Comment: So it was actually the `with` syntax which I was looking for: `subset(x, A>1)` vs. `with(x, A>1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%   
  mutate(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(str_c(cond$condition, collapse=";"))) %>% 
  rename_at(3:4, ~ paste0("condition", 1:2))
#  A B condition1 condition2
#1 1 2      FALSE      FALSE
#2 2 3       TRUE       TRUE
#3 3 4       TRUE      FALSE
```

If needed, the `logical` columns can be easily converted to binary with `as.integer`