# Replacing an if statement's condition character with a variable

Tags: r, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is probably an easy one.

In `R`, can I replace an `if` condition character (such as `>`) with a `character` and execute the `if` `statement` with it?

For example, if the `if` `statement` is:

```
ifelse(1 < 2, "T", "F")
```

But I'm getting the `>` condition character through a variable:

```
cc <- ">"
```

How would I write:

```
ifelse(1 < 2, "T", "F")
```

replacing `<` with `cc`?

Comment: Very close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807468/evaluate-different-logical-conditions-from-string-for-each-row/ since all answers there can be applied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a relational operator in R, we can use `match.fun`

```
cc <- "<"
ifelse(match.fun(cc)(1, 2), "T", "F")
#[1] "T"
```

This `ifelse` can be simplified but I assume this is just an example and you want to do something more complicated.

---

You can also get the required output using `eval(parse..` but I would not recommend it

```
ifelse(eval(parse(text = paste(1, cc, 2))), "T", "F")
#[1] "T"
```