# Parse and Evaluate Column of String Expressions in R?

Tags: r, parsing, dplyr, eval, rlang

How can I parse and evaluate a column of string expressions in R as part of a pipeline?

In the example below, I produce my desired column, `evaluated`. But I know this isn't the right approach. I tried taking a tidyverse approach. But I'm just very confused.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(name = LETTERS[1:3], 
             to_evaluate = c("1-1+1", "iter+iter", "4*iter-1"), 
             evaluated = NA)
iter = 1
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[i,"evaluated"] <- eval(parse(text=df$to_evaluate[[i]]))
}
print(df)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# name  to_evaluate evaluated
# <chr> <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 A     1-1+1               1
# 2 B     iter+iter           2
# 3 C     4*iter-1            3
```

As part of a pipeline, I tried:

```
df %>% mutate(evaluated = eval(parse(text=to_evaluate)))
df %>% mutate(evaluated = !!parse_exprs(to_evaluate))
df %>% mutate(evaluated = parse_exprs(to_evaluate))
df %>% mutate(evaluated = eval(parse_expr(to_evaluate)))
df %>% mutate(evaluated = parse_exprs(to_evaluate))
df %>% mutate(evaluated = eval(parse_exprs(to_evaluate)))
df %>% mutate(evaluated = eval_tidy(parse_exprs(to_evaluate)))
```

None of these work.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807468/evaluate-different-logical-conditions-from-string-for-each-row/

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(iter = 1,
        evaluated = eval(parse(text = to_evaluate))) %>%
 select(-iter)

  name  to_evaluate evaluated
  <chr> <chr>           <dbl>
1 A     1-1+1               1
2 B     iter+iter           2
3 C     4*iter-1            3
```

Following this logic, also other possibilities could work. Using `rlang::parse_expr()`:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(iter = 1,
        evaluated = eval(rlang::parse_expr(to_evaluate))) %>%
 select(-iter)
```

On the other hand, I think it is important to quote [@Martin Mächler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743698/evaluate-expression-given-as-a-string):

> The (possibly) only connection is via parse(text = ....) and all good
>   R programmers should know that this is rarely an efficient or safe
>   means to construct expressions (or calls). Rather learn more about
>   substitute(), quote(), and possibly the power of using
>   do.call(substitute, ......).

Comment: You can do all of this with mutate and pmap and well. `df %>% mutate(evaluated = pmap_dbl(., function(name, to_evaluate, evaluated) eval(parse(text=to_evaluate))))`

Comment: @rpolicastro I think it is worth of a separate post, please consider posting it :)

Comment: I'll post another answer for it, thanks. Wasn't sure if it was different enough from yours to be worth it.

Comment: This simplifies your second solution a bit: `iter <- 1; df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(evaluated = eval(rlang::parse_expr(to_evaluate)))`. No need to define `iter` in the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different way that does everything within mutate.

```
df %>% mutate(
    evaluated = pmap_dbl(., function(name, to_evaluate, evaluated) 
                         eval(parse(text=to_evaluate)))
)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name  to_evaluate evaluated
  <chr> <chr>           <dbl>
1 A     1-1+1               1
2 B     iter+iter           2
3 C     4*iter-1            3
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that values of additional variables (such as `iter=1` in your case) can be passed directly to `eval()`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate( evaluated = map_dbl(to_evaluate, ~eval(parse(text=.x), list(iter=1))) )
```

One advantage is that it automatically restricts the scope of the variable, keeping its value right next to where it is used.