# Is there a way to use operators that are elements in a column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, operators

The actual goal is much broader than this but right in the middle of it all I need to perform equations where the operator is one of the values in a data frame. The sample code replicates three columns in the formats they are in from the df being used.   In this example df, I would want to perform the operations 20+5, 10-10 and 5*15.

```
# R code for sample df
a <- c(20,10,5)
b <- as.character(c("+","-","*"))
c <- c(5,10,15)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A considerably clear way using `dplyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(d = case_when(b == "+" ~ a + c,
                      b == "-" ~ a - c,
                      TRUE ~ a * c))
```

Here you essentially define the relations. As there is not that many operators, it is not that problematic.

Another way, already outlined by @Gregor involves `eval(parse(...))`:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(d = paste(a, b, c),
        d = eval(parse(text = d)))
```

However, you should use it carefully. See [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(…))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

Comment: This will perform poorly (solely by the nature of `case_when`, your implementation is clear and idiomatic to it), you might consider `group_by(b)` and using a simpler `if` sequence for vectorized calculations. Perhaps slightly messy compared to this, but almost certainly faster (if data size is a factor).

Comment: @r2evans thank you for noting it :) I was never really thinking about `case_when()` in terms of performance.

Comment: I don't think it was suggested in the question that data size would be large, in which case the iterative nature of `case_when` should perform well within normal "perception tolerances".

Comment: tmfmnk solution worked perfectly.  Before reaching out I was butchering if statements.  r2evans made me go back and look at that again and mutate(if_else...) worked very well also.  I did not however use group_by, just straight mutate(if_else...)  size in this case is not an issue.  Could size or something else be a factor in wanting to incorporate group_by(b) with if sequence instead of mutate(if_else) or should I just be happy with the wonderful solutions and get on with my life and not overthink this?

Comment: I personally think that it could affect performance only marginally. And even that just in the case of very large datasets (tens of millions rows) :) But if speed is a concern, then you can run a benchmark (see the library `microbenchmark`) and see how different possibilities behave.

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(with(df, paste(a, b, c)), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
 20 + 5 10 - 10  5 * 15 
     25       0      75
```

But beware! Things can get very messy when you go down this path. Fragile, and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using simple primitive binary operands, you can get the functions and apply them to the values. For example

```
with(df, mapply(function(op,x,y) {op(x, y)}, 
  mget(as.character(b), inherits=TRUE), a, c))
```

Here we use `mget()` to get the functions for each of the operators and then use `mapply()` to pass the other columns as parameters.