# Create a list of functions dynamically with stored variables?

Tags: r, tidyr

Hi I like to create a list of functions dynamically.  The only thing is that I have stored variables that I like to input as my function.  For example, say I have a named vector with color.

```
color = c("blue","red")
names ( color) = c("a","b")
```

Now I want to create a list of dynamic function returning the color.

```
c = list()

for ( n in names ( color)){
    c[[n]]= function ( x){
        return ( color[n])
    }
}
```

however as you can see it returns "color[n]" and not the evaluated value.

```
> c$a
function ( x){
        return ( color[n])
    }
<bytecode: 0x0000000105e0a108>
```

Comment: What's your end goal here? to get the names of the colours in to a list? `as.list(names(color)` would achieve this.

Comment: @JonnyPhelps no that was just an example. I need to create functions that is specific to each round of the loop.  Color was just an example I came up with.

Comment: Use `c$a()`? Returns `"red"`.

Comment: For what reason? I'm struggling to think of a practical use case as you can usually achieve these results by making one function and then looping the function over the variable set e.g. with `lapply` https://www.guru99.com/r-apply-sapply-tapply.html

Comment: @M.Papenberg yes but it's just finding `color` in the global environment. Change `color[2] = "hi"` and `c[[2]]()` will now return `"hi"`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer uses the `eval(parse(…))` construct, which has its flaws ([What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(...))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)). But you could try:

```
for (n in names(color)) {
  c[[n]] <- eval(parse(text = sprintf("function(x) return(color['%s'])", n)))
}

c
# $`a`
# function (x) 
# return(color["a"])

# $b
# function (x) 
# return(color["b"])

c$a()
#      a 
# "blue"
```

But as commenters (to your question, and elsewhere on SO) have suggested, there may be more elegant solutions to your problem, depending on your context and use case.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I have realised based on the above answers that you want to have a function where you then probably want to pass further arguments.

Here is the code with `eval(expr())`-statement. It's maybe better readable than the above answers, but not really different.

```
c = list()
for ( n in names (color)){
  c[[n]]= eval(expr(function(x) {return(color[(!!n)])}))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  something like this:

```r
color = c("blue","red")
names ( color) = c("a","b")

c = list()

for ( n in names ( color)){

  eval(
    parse(
      text = paste0(
        "
c[[n]]= function ( x){
    return ('", color[n],"')
  }"
      )
    )
  )
}
c$a
#> function ( x){
#>     return ('blue')
#>   }
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method:

```
c = list()
for ( n in names ( color)) {
  c[[n]] <- (function(n) {
    force(n)
    function (x) return ( color[n])
  })(n)
}
```

Note this creates functions as you requested, which means you need to call then with `()` to get the values returned. For example

```
c$a()
#      a 
# "blue" 
c$b()
#     b 
# "red"
```

Or it's even easier if you replace the `for` loop `with`Map`

```
c <- Map(function(n) {
  function(x) color[n]
}, names(color)) 

c$a()
#      a 
# "blue" 
c$b()
#     b 
# "red"
```