# Shiny Numeric input - add calculation

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to know if there's a way to accept calculation (ex : 30/365 + 15) in shiny NumericInput.

Thanks

Comment: No, but you can use a text input and evaluate the operation with Ryacas - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61033227/in-shiny-how-to-insert-math-symbols-in-a-text-input-so-that-my-r-code-performs/61060509#61060509)

Comment: Thanks ! Working perfectly!