# How to pass a filter statement as a function parameter in dplyr using quosure

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, quosure

Using the `dplyr` package in `R`, I want to pass a filter statement as a parameter in a function. I don't know how to evaluate the statement as code instead of a string. When I try the code below, I get an error message. I'm assuming I need a quosure or something, but I don't fully grasp that concept.

```
data("PlantGrowth")

myfunc <- function(df, filter_statement) {
  df %>%
    filter(!!filter_statement)
}

myfunc(PlantGrowth, "group %in% c('trt1', 'trt2')")

>  Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector 

# Want to do the same as this:
# PlantGrowth %>%
#   filter(group %in% c('trt1', 'trt2'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `parse_expr` from `rlang`

```
library(dplyr)

myfunc <- function(df, filter_statement) {
   df %>% filter(eval(rlang::parse_expr(filter_statement)))
}

identical(myfunc(PlantGrowth, "group %in% c('trt1', 'trt2')"), 
      PlantGrowth %>% filter(group %in% c('trt1', 'trt2')))

#[1] TRUE
```

The same can be done using  [infamous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) `eval` and `parse`.

```
myfunc <- function(df, filter_statement) {
   df %>% filter(eval(parse(text = filter_statement)))
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you! I never understand when to use `!!` or `quo()` or `eval()`...

Comment: Same. For me it's always trial and error ;-)

Comment: Interesting that `eval/parse` is frowned upon. However, `parse_exprs` includes a call to `parse(text=)` which in my opinion looks like the same thing named differently. Perhaps I should learn how `!!` works but often it seems like masking what is being done in `base`

Comment: Yes, personally I would prefer to pass `group` and `c('trt1', 'trt2')` as two separate parameters instead of passing condition in the string `"group %in% c('trt1', 'trt2')"` and evaluating it.