# Pasting list in different ways

Tags: r

Below code is returning a tibble as expected that is fine

Method1

```
df <- tibble(ID = 1:2,
             ColB = list(list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11") ,
                         list(ved = c("65", "83", "2"), ved_name = c("At", "Re", "Rum"),
                              vedd = c("11", "11", "11"))))
```

Below is the output

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID ColB            
  <int> <list>          
1     1 <named list [3]>
2     2 <named list [3]>
```

But if I try performing above in different way, I am not able to

Method2

There is a list already

```
List_1
[[1]]
[1] "list(list(ved = "19", ved_name = "No", vedd = "11") ,
                         list(ved = c("65", "83", "2"), ved_name = c("At", "Re", "Rum"),
                              vedd = c("11", "11", "11")))"
```

When I execute below code, the output is different

```
df <- tibble(ID = 1: 2, ColB = List_1)
df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     ID ColB     
  <int> <list>   
1    11 <chr [1]
2    12 <chr [1]>
```

There is a difference. So the exepected output is getting Output of Method1 using Method2 steps.Is this possible to achieve

```
dput(List1)
list("list(list(ved = \"19\", ved_name = \"No\", vedd = \"11\") ,
                         list(ved = c(\"65\", \"83\", \"2\"), ved_name = c(\"At\", \"Re\", \"Rum\"),
                              vedd = c(\"11\", \"11\", \"11\")))")
```

Comment: No, It is not :)

Comment: Add `dput(List_1)` to your post.

Comment: Added :)...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List1`  is list of length 1 with string. To read that as list as in your first example you can use `eval`, `parse`. And if you are using it also read [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(...))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) .

```
df <- tibble::tibble(ID = 1:2,
                     ColB = eval(parse(text = list1[[1]])))
df
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID ColB            
#  <int> <list>          
#1     1 <named list [3]>
#2     2 <named list [3]>
```

Comment: Just awesome dude :) Thanks a lot