# Evaluating a function pointed to by a string in R

Tags: r, string, function, evaluate

Suppose I have the following:

```
   x <- 1:10  
   squared <- function(x) {x^2}  
   y <- "squared"
```

I want to be able to evaluate the function using the string defined by y.  Something like eval(y), which I know is wrong, but will return

[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100

> 

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Another option is: `do.call(y, list(x))`.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) discuss why you might want to avoid `eval(parse` in favor of other alternatives that are easier to understand and debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `match.fun`

```
match.fun(y)(x)
#[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

or with `get`

```
get(y)(x)
#[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

Answer (score 1):

To tell `R` that a given string is rather a command than a simple string, use `eval(parse(text=...))`.

Therefore, you could do

```
eval(parse(text=y))(x)
```

where `eval(parse(text=y))` returns a function encoded in the string in `y` and `x` is the functions argument.

Moreover you could simply use `match.fun`, which looks whether there is a function with a specific name in the environment and grabs this function. Then then apply it to the argument `x` like

```
match.fun(y)(x)
```

Comment: That works.  I did not realize you could add the (x) to the end of the eval-parse function.  thanks.