# How to specify an arbitrary amount of variables in aes in a generic function in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I am making a shiny application where the user specifies the independent variables and as a result shiny displays a time series plot with plotly, where on-however each point shows the selected parameters.

[image]
[image]

If I know the exact number of variables that the user selects, I am able to construct the time series plot without a problem. Let's say there are 3 parameters chosen:

```
ggp <- ggplot(data = data.depend(), aes(x = Datum, y = y, tmp1 = .data[[input$Coockpit.Dependencies.Undependables[1]]], tmp2 = .data[[input$Coockpit.Dependencies.Undependables[2]]], tmp3 = .data[[input$Coockpit.Dependencies.Undependables[3]]])) + 
     geom_point()
ggplotly(ggp)
```

where data.depend() looks like
[image]

and the selected parameters are stored in a character vector [image]

So the problem is that for each parameter I want to include in the tooltip, I have to hard code it in the aes function as tmpi = .data[[input$Coockpit.Dependencies.Undependables[i]]]. I would however like to write generic function that handles any amount of selected parameters. Any comment suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
Below a minimal working example:

```
data.dummy <- data.frame(Charge = c(1,2,3,4,5), Datum = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-01-02"),as.Date("2020-01-03"),as.Date("2020-01-04"),as.Date("2020-01-05")), y = c(4,5,6,4,5), ZuluftTemperatur = c(52,51,54,58,49), Durchflussgeschwindigkeit = c(690, 716,722,710,801), ZuluftFeuchtigkeit= c(3.9,4.1,3.8,3.0,4.9))
ChosenParams <- c("ZuluftTemperatur", "ZuluftFeuchtigkeit", "Durchflussgeschwindigkeit")
ggp <- ggplot(data = data.dummy, aes(x = Datum, y = y,  tmp1 = .data[[ChosenParams[1]]], tmp2 = .data[[ChosenParams[2]]], tmp3 = .data[[ChosenParams[3]]])) + geom_point()
ggplotly(ggp)
```

Result:

[image]

So this works at the "cost" of me knowing the user is choosing three parameters and therefore I write in aes tmpi = .data[[ChosenParams[i]]]; i=1:3. I am interested in a solution with the same result but where I don't have to write tmpi = .data[[ChosenParams[i]]] i-number of times

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()` and use the `reprex`-package.

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off converting your data to long format (`pivot_longer()`) before plotting, but as @mnist says, without a MRE, it's not easy to help.

Comment: Now with a MRE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `eval(parse(...))` to create the code for you:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data.dummy <- data.frame(Charge = c(1,2,3,4,5), Datum = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-01-02"),as.Date("2020-01-03"),as.Date("2020-01-04"),as.Date("2020-01-05")), y = c(4,5,6,4,5), ZuluftTemperatur = c(52,51,54,58,49), Durchflussgeschwindigkeit = c(690, 716,722,710,801), ZuluftFeuchtigkeit= c(3.9,4.1,3.8,3.0,4.9))
ChosenParams <- c("ZuluftTemperatur", "ZuluftFeuchtigkeit", "Durchflussgeschwindigkeit")

ggp <- eval(parse(text = paste0("ggplot(data = data.dummy, aes(x = Datum, y = y, ",
                                paste0("tmp", seq_along(ChosenParams), " = .data[[ChosenParams[", seq_along(ChosenParams), "]]]", collapse = ", "),
                                ")) + geom_point()"
                                )
                  ))

            
ggplotly(ggp)
```

Just note that this is not very efficient and in some cases it is not advised to use it (see [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(...))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)). There might also be a way to use quasiquotation in `aes()`, but I am not really familiar with it.

EDIT: Added a way to do it with quasiquotation.

I had a look a closer look at quasiquotations in `aes()` and found a nicer way to do it using `syms()` and `!!!`:

```r
data.dummy <- data.frame(Charge = c(1,2,3,4,5), Datum = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-01-02"),as.Date("2020-01-03"),as.Date("2020-01-04"),as.Date("2020-01-05")), y = c(4,5,6,4,5), ZuluftTemperatur = c(52,51,54,58,49), Durchflussgeschwindigkeit = c(690, 716,722,710,801), ZuluftFeuchtigkeit= c(3.9,4.1,3.8,3.0,4.9))
ChosenParams <- c("ZuluftTemperatur", "ZuluftFeuchtigkeit", "Durchflussgeschwindigkeit")
names(ChosenParams) <- paste0("tmp", seq_along(ChosenParams))
ChosenParams <- syms(ChosenParams)

ggp <- ggplot(data = data.dummy, aes(x = Datum, y = y, !!!ChosenParams)) + geom_point()
ggplotly(ggp)
```

Comment: @RokBohinc Because I was interested in how it works withtout using `eval(parse(...))` I had a closer look at quasiquotations in `aes()` and saw a nicer, cleaner way to do it, see my edit.

Comment: Works even better. Where did you dig out the information about syms() and the quasinotation (I assume this is the !!! operator). Were can I learn more about that?

Comment: @RokBohinc In the help pages of `aes()` you find a section called Quasiquotation and in there if you click on quasiquotation you get to a help page "Force parts of an expression" and there I found the information. Or you just search `nse-force` in the R help to get there.