# How to pass an object from outside a R-function to the function's body?

Tags: r, function

I want to pass the content of an object that is defined outside a function to the function's body.
My problem might be easier to understand with an example:

```
a <- 'hello world'
foo <- function() print(a)
rm(a)
foo()
```

Currently, this obviously throws an error, because `a` is not defined anymore when calling `foo()`.

My desired outcome is that I want `foo` to look like  `function() print('hello world')`

Comment: Just [build a closure](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) local** Capture `a` using a `local` like this.   This fixes the value of `a` to what it was when `foo` was defined. Note that the `a` on the right hand side of `a <- a` is the `a` already defined whereas the `a` on the left hand side is a new object, also called `a`, that is defined within the `local`.  No packages are used.

```
a <- 'hello world'
foo <- local({
  a <- a
  function() print(a)
})

rm(a)
foo()
## [1] "hello world"
```

**2) substitute** Another alternative is to substitute the value of `a` into the body of `foo` like this.  This fixes `a` in `foo` to the value that it was when the `substitute` is run.  No packages are used.

```
foo <- function() print(a)

a <- 'hello world'
body(foo) <- do.call("substitute", list(body(foo), list(a = a)))

rm(a)
foo()
## [1] "hello world"
```

**3) function which generates foo**  Another possibility is to create a function which generates foo.  Note that R uses lazy evaluation so we need to use `force` to ensure that the value of `a` at the time that `foogen` runs is used; otherwise, it will delay the evaluation until after `a` is removed causing an error.  This fixes `a` in `foo` to the value that is passed to `foogen`.  No packages are used.

```
foogen <- function(a) {
  force(a)
  function() print(a)
}

a <- 'hello world'
foo <- foogen(a)
rm(a)
foo()
## [1] "hello world"
```

**4) proto** The proto package can be used to create an object `p` containing both `foo` and `a`.

```
library(proto)

p <- proto(foo = function(.) print(a))

a <- 'hello world'
p$a <- a
rm(a)
p$foo()
## [1] "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `eval(parse(...))` here, or an external package. Using `eval` and `parse` is [generally not a good idea for a few different reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse), including the amount of fun that a malicious user could have exploiting it. This is becoming increasingly relevant as R is used more and more in web apps that accept user input.

There are a few ways to do this in base R without `eval(parse(...))` or any external dependencies. One approach is to have a function factory:

```r
a <- 'hello world'
foo_maker <- function(x) as.function(list(x = a, quote(print(x))))
```

So now we can do:

```
foo <- foo_maker(a)
rm(a)
foo()
#> [1] "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to solve the problem using the `whisker` package and `eval(parse(...))`:

```
library(whisker)
a <- 'hello world'
foo <- eval(parse(text = whisker.render('function() print("{{b}}")', 
                                        data = list(b = a))))
foo()
rm(a)
foo()
```