# How to eval(parse(text= var_name), envir= df) if var_name is a number?

Tags: r, parsing, variables, eval, names

Using eval I make different stuff with variables. Here is an example where simply the variable `a` is returned without any transformations:

```
df <- data.frame(1:10); var_name <- "a"
names(df) <- var_name
eval(parse(text= var_name), envir= df) 
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

This works as expected. But if I call a column name as a number, e.g. `3`, this does not return the expected vector `1:10`:

```
df <- data.frame(1:10); var_name <- "3"
names(df) <- var_name
eval(parse(text= var_name), envir= df)
[1] 3
```

I understand that in first example I get the expected output because `eval(...)` is same as saving `a` as a variable in the global environment and then calling it, i.e. `a <- df$a; a`. On the other hand, the second example is same as typing `3` which returns `[1] 3`. Is there a way to make clear that even with numbers we want `eval(...)` to look for variable names in the `envir` argument?

All I've come up with is eval(parse(text= "`3`"), envir= df) but I need a solution where I can provide the variable name with the vector `var_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options here. You could wrap `var_name` in `as.symbol`

```r
df <- data.frame(1:10); var_name <- "3"
names(df) <- var_name
eval(as.symbol(var_name), envir = df)
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Or, possibly simpler, you could use `get` instead:

```r
df <- data.frame(1:10); var_name <- "3"
names(df) <- var_name
get(var_name, envir = as.environment(df))
#> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Note though that passing strings around as objects to be parsed into code is generally bad practice, whether you use `get` or `eval` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse) for a few reasons why.

Comment: Maybe you could see this question about eval being bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71663044/evalparse-some-string-is-bad-practice-but-what-alternative-is-recommende