# Evaluate condition stored in character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I evaluate an `ifelse()` statement using a condition stored in a character vector?

For example:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
condition <- ">"

ifelse(a condition b, print("good"), print("bad))
```

Comment: Why is it stored as a character string? You should avoid that.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this:

```
ifelse(eval(parse(text = paste0(a, condition, b))), 'good', 'bad')
```

Comment: No, never do that. It's bad practice, inefficient and a nightmare to debug.

Comment: @Roland. Could please comment on why never do that. Many thanks.

Comment: @Roland Yes I didn't know this. I just read Ronak's comment and realized the reason why we have to avoid it. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option with `match.fun` -

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
condition <- ">"
if(match.fun(condition)(a, b)) 'good' else 'bad'
#[1] "bad"
```

Since this is a scalar comparison I'm using `if`/`else` instead of vectorised `ifelse`. If `a` and `b` are vectors use `ifelse`.

[Some readings about why `eval(parse(...))` is bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse)

I agree with @Roland's comment that we should avoid saving `condition` as character to avoid this problem completely. However, sometimes it is not possible to do that. I have experienced such situation especially while working with shiny applications where we want to apply such functions on the fly, in such case, I use `match.fun` option.

Comment: Very helpful insights here, and a small rabbit-hole to go down for reasons and alternatives. `get(condition)(a, b)` technically works as well, but `match.fun` seems much more reliable!

Comment: Thanks Ronak for the links. I wasn't aware of this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Also would work:

```
ifelse(do.call(condition, list(a, b)), "good", "bad")
```

As `>` is a function in R.

Comment: This is so elegant :)