# How to pass a named argument stored in a string to list() in R

Tags: r

If I have a string like:

```r
s <- "x = 1"
```

how do I pass this to `list()` and end up with a list with one element named "x" and equal to 1. Like this:

```r
list(x = 1)
```

I tried:

```r
list(eval(str2lang(s)))
```

I know one way to do this:

```r
s2 <- strsplit(s, " = ")[[1]]

stats::setNames(list(s2[2]), s2[1])
```

I don't like the above solution, however, because it produces double and singles quotes if the value being assigned inside the list is already quoted:

```r
s <- "x = 'a'"
s2 <- strsplit(s, " = ")[[1]]

lst1 <- stats::setNames(list(s2[2]), s2[1])

lst2 <- list(x = 'a')

all.equal(lst1, lst2)
```

### Update

A number of solutions have been offered, but none seem to do quite what I had in mind when I say "how do I pass [a string] to `list()`".

This is what I mean:

```r
list(x = 'z', y = 1, some_function("x = 'a'"))
```

where `some_function` can take a string, parse the expression inside, and then have it evaluated as if it were just another named object being passed to `list()`.

Comment: `eval(str2lang(sprintf('list(%s)',s)))` should work. But why have a string in the first place?

Comment: Well, I'm considering adding an argument in a config file that determines specific filtering criteria for an entry in the config file, and the argument would a string. But mostly I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
f <- function(string){
  a <- str2lang(string)
  as.list(setNames(a[[3]], as.character(a[[2]])))
}

s1 <- "x = 'a'"
s <- "x = 1"

f(s)
#> $x
#> [1] 1
f(s1)
#> $x
#> [1] "a"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Using `eval`, you could do:

```
 eval(str2lang(sprintf('list(%s)',s)))
```

Comment: I think I might even like your commented answer more: `eval(str2lang(sprintf('list(%s)',s)))`, just because it's more concise. But I was really looking for some solution that would go inside like `list(x = 'z', y = 1, some_function("x = 'a'"))`.

Comment: @GiovanniColitti the problem you stated in this comment is different from the one you asked. If the comment works, thats fine. Will add it in this solution too. I was trying to avoid the use of `eval` as it has potential downside.

Comment: What is the potential downside of using `eval` here?

Comment: @GiovanniColitti in this example i do not see any, though in general better avoid evaluating strings. `eval` is better used to evaluate quoted/unevaluated expressions. try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse#comment18731187_13649979)

Answer (score 1):

```r
s = "x = 1"

env <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
env[["list"]] <- base::list

eval(str2lang(paste0("list(", s, ")")), env)
#> $x
#> [1] 1
```

The empty `env` environment is in order to prevent running code other than "list".

Comment: Similar idea building on what you have - `l <- new.env(); eval(str2lang(s), envir=l); as.list.environment(l)`