# Converting string column into formula

Tags: r, string, formula, eval

I'm trying to convert strings from a column into formulas and output the result based on values I specify. For example:

```r
Compo <- c("FE56", "FE58", "FE61", "YI68", "FE11")
Formula <- c("( FE13 / 0.06 ) * CE68", 
             "( ( CE01 + CE02 + CE03 ) / 100 ) * ( 393682 / 10000 )", 
             "FE12 / 0.06", 
             "CE68", 
             "FQ11")
table <- data.frame(Compo, Formula) 

FE13 <- 13
CE68 <- 20
CE01 <- 5
CE02 <- 15
CE03 <- 5.067
FE12 <- 35
FQ11 <-37

table$resultado <- parse(text = tabela$Formula)
table$results <- eval(tabela$resultado)
```

The output:
[image]

But the column `results` only returns the value from the last formula, when it supposed to return the result from each formula.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your results in a textual format (i.e., not a screenshot/image)?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create a vectorized and customized function:

```
parse_string_formula <- function(formula){
  return(eval(parse(text = formula)))
}
parse_string_formula <- Vectorize(parse_string_formula)

table$final_result <- parse_string_formula(table$Formula)

  Compo                                               Formula       final_result
1  FE56                                ( FE13 / 0.06 ) * CE68 4333.3333333333339
2  FE58 ( ( CE01 + CE02 + CE03 ) / 100 ) * ( 393682 / 10000 )    9.8684266940000
3  FE61                                           FE12 / 0.06  583.3333333333334
4  YI68                                                  CE68   20.0000000000000
5  FE11                                                  FQ11   37.0000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with `dplyr` if you make the parameter values variables in the data.  Sometimes people advise against the `eval()`, `parse()` combination, so this uses the tidy versions of these same concepts:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

Compo <- c("FE56", "FE58", "FE61", "YI68", "FE11")
Formula <- c("( FE13 / 0.06 ) * CE68", "( ( CE01 + CE02 + CE03 ) / 100 ) * ( 393682 / 10000 )", "FE12 / 0.06", "CE68", "FQ11")
table <- data.frame(Compo, Formula) 

params <- data.frame(
  FE13 =  13,
CE68 =  20,
CE01 =  5,
CE02 =  15,
CE03 =  5.067,
FE12 =  35,
FQ11 = 37)

table <- bind_cols(table, params)
table <- table %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(result = eval_tidy(parse_expr(Formula))) %>% 
  select(1,2,result)
table
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   Compo Formula                                                result
#>   <chr> <chr>                                                   <dbl>
#> 1 FE56  ( FE13 / 0.06 ) * CE68                                4333.  
#> 2 FE58  ( ( CE01 + CE02 + CE03 ) / 100 ) * ( 393682 / 10000 )    9.87
#> 3 FE61  FE12 / 0.06                                            583.  
#> 4 YI68  CE68                                                    20   
#> 5 FE11  FQ11                                                    37
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't think the advice against using eval/parse is specific to the base R eval/parse. I gather it was more to do with not storing code as text strings in the first place, when there's often a better way to do it. Though for this particular question where that has already occurred, there's not a whole lot of alternatives.

Comment: @thelatemail - there are some other concerns [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse), but I think you're right that if you get this far, there aren't many other options.