# Get vector from a dataframe column named in a string through '$' operator

Tags: r, get

I am trying to automatically get, in a loop, a column from a dataframe. It is important to get this column by '$' operator `df$column`, because if I slice the df like this `df[,c('column')]` then I don't get anymore a haven_labelled object.

Example `df`:

```
colName  colName2
a         1
b         2
c         3
d         4
```

I was trying `get(paste0('df$', colName))`, but I am getting:

```
Error in get(paste0('df$', colName)) : object 'df$colName' not found
```

However, if I write: `df$colName` in my console, the column is printed. So the problem is that get only identifies the df as an object, but not its columns. Do you know how can I solve this?

What I would like is to get the following vector: `c('a','b','c','d')`, but it must keep its labels.

Thanks!

Comment: You can retrieve columns from a df with `df[[colName]]`. Anyhow, why not `lapply` or `Map` across the dataframe (which is a *list*, albeit a rectangular one), or `dplyr::across` if you prefer tidyverse packages?

Comment: This seems like a bit of an xy problem. It doesn't have anything to do with the `$` operator. If I put a haven labelled column in a data frame, then `df$colName`, `df[['colName']]` and `df[, c('colName')]` all return a haven labelled vector. Can you provide a reproducible example that replicates your problem?

Comment: Maybe you can use: `eval(parse(text = paste0('df$', colName)))` ?

Comment: Using `eval(parse(...))` is generally discouraged, see this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse