# How to create and then execute a command during run time in R?

Tags: r

I'm writing an agent model and one of the commands will be developed during run time. This is what I'm doing but I would love to hear better alternatives.

1. create the command as a string using paste
2. execute the command within the agent model code with eval

Something like:

```
a <- 0
#Create the command
x <- 50
ex <- paste('if (', x , '> 10) {a = 100}')

#Agent model code
y <- 100
eval(parse(text = ex))
z <- 200
```

Is this a bad idea?

Comment: See [What specifically are the dangers of eval(parse(...))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse). It's generally not the best approach (and often it's the worst). Clearly there is a reason you can't just write the line `if ( 50 > 10) {a = 100}"`, but I don't understand what it is. What is actually provided during run time, the value of `x`? How is it provided?

Comment: The behaviour of the agents is unknown at the start of the agent run. They are going to learn how to behave as they go using AI. The AI will output a command, insert it into the agent model, run the agent model, assess the output for fitness and repeat. It won't be a fast program! X is just an example to illustrate the technique I'm planning to use to execute the learned behaviour.

Comment: Could you use a recursive function?