# Writing variables column names to df dynamically

Tags: r, dataframe

```
var3<- c(1,2,3)
var2<- c(4,5,6)
var1 <- c(7,8,9)

df<-data.frame(var1,var2,var3)


for (i in (3:2))
{
eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i))) - eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i-1)))


}
```

For each cycle through the loop I want to write the difference (result of this line : eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i))) - eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i-1))) to the data frame.

I was trying something like this:

```
assign(paste0('df$','var3_minus_var2') ,eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i))) - eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i-1))))
```

OR

```
paste0('df$','var3_minus_var2') <- eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i))) - eval(parse(text=paste0('df$var',i-1)))
```

I would like to write the new dataframe names to the dataframe dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `eval(parse(...))` in your code. It is not [safe way to write code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse).

Here is one way where you create columns dynamically from your data and subtract the consecutive columns.

```
col1 <- names(df)[-1]
col2 <- names(df)[-ncol(df)]
cols <- paste(col1, col2, sep = "_minus_")
df[cols] <- df[col1] - df[col2]
df

#  var1 var2 var3 var2_minus_var1 var3_minus_var2
#1    7    4    1              -3              -3
#2    8    5    2              -3              -3
#3    9    6    3              -3              -3
```

where the variables are -

```
col1
#[1] "var2" "var3"

col2
#[1] "var1" "var2"

cols
#[1] "var2_minus_var1" "var3_minus_var2"
```