Variable column names in rowwise dplyr
There are a number of similar questions on SO, but those typically about applying a simple sum or mean, or for some other reason the situation can be largely simplified. Here I want to copy the values of certain columns under keys within a list of lists column. Here is a minimal example:
Setup
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)

keys <- c('a', 'b')

tbl <-
    tibble(
        x = list(
            list(f = 'foo', g = 'bar'),
            list(f = 'bar', g = 'foo')
        ),
        a = list(
            list(i = 1, j = 2),
            list(i = 4, j = 7)
        ),
        b = list(
            list(i = 5, j = 3),
            list(i = 2, j = 9)
        )
    )

This works and does what I wish for:
i.e. in the first element of x, under keys a and b there are the first values of columns a and b, respectively
tbl2 <-
    tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
        x = list(x %>% inset2('a', a) %>% inset2('b', b))
    )

However, let's imagine we have 12 keys, that would mean 12 inset2 calls. It would be nice to handle them together or loop through them. I attempted this with purrr::reduce, however, I couldn't find a way to access the source columns within reduce:
Iterating the keys and trying to use them as a character index on .data:
tbl2 <-
    tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
        x = list(
            reduce(
                keys,
                function(lst, key) {
                    inset2(lst, key, .data[[key]])
                },
                .init = x
            )
        )
    )

Error: object 'key' not found
7: quos(..., .ignore_empty = "all")
6: dplyr_quosures(...)
5: force(dots)
4: mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
3: mutate.data.frame(., x = list(reduce(keys, function(lst, key) {
       inset2(lst, key, .data[[key]])
   }, .init = x)))
2: mutate(., x = list(reduce(keys, function(lst, key) {
       inset2(lst, key, .data[[key]])
   }, .init = x)))
1: tbl %>% rowwise %>% mutate(x = list(reduce(keys, function(lst,
       key) {
       inset2(lst, key, .data[[key]])
   }, .init = x)))

The above error happens only in .data, key itself, as expected, exists as a string within the function. I also tried to convert key to a symbol:
tbl2 <-
    tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
        x = list(
            reduce(
                keys,
                function(lst, key) {
                    inset2(lst, key, !!sym(key))
                },
                .init = x
            )
        )
    )

Error: object 'key' not found
9: is_symbol(x)
8: sym(key)
7: quos(..., .ignore_empty = "all")
6: dplyr_quosures(...)
5: force(dots)
4: mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
3: mutate.data.frame(., x = list(reduce(keys, function(lst, key) {
       inset2(lst, key, !!sym(key))
   }, .init = x)))
2: mutate(., x = list(reduce(keys, function(lst, key) {
       inset2(lst, key, !!sym(key))
   }, .init = x)))
1: tbl %>% rowwise %>% mutate(x = list(reduce(keys, function(lst,
       key) {
       inset2(lst, key, !!sym(key))
   }, .init = x)))

This version runs without error, but assigns the actual symbols (a, b, ...) to the list instead their values from the row:
tbl2 <-
    tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
        x = list(
            reduce(
                keys,
                function(lst, key) {
                    inset2(lst, key, sym(key))
                },
                .init = x
            )
        )
    )

tbl2$x[[1]]$a
a  # this `a` is a symbol

Then I tried to resolve the keys first and supposedly pass the values to the function, though I'm not sure what val contains below. It runs without error, but all values in x will be NULL. I think it means !!!syms(keys) returns NULL, hence reduce2 does zero loops, and returns NULL.
tbl2 <-
    tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
        x = list(
            reduce2(
                keys,
                !!!syms(keys),
                function(lst, key, val) {
                    inset2(lst, key, val)
                },
                .init = x
            )
        )
    )

Finally I returned to the idea of using keys as character vector, and relying on .data. Also, probably it's more efficient to do the whole operation in one go, instead of moving the elements key by key. So I tried to extract all elements and move them by utils::modifyList:
tbl2 <-
    tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
        x = list(modifyList(x, .data[keys]))
    )

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `x = list(modifyList(x, .data[keys]))`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `.data[keys]`:
! `[` is not supported by the `.data` pronoun, use `[[` or $ instead.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

At this point, I found an actual solution that I'll post as an answer. But I think this is an interesting example, and I'm wondering if someone comes up with a trivial solution that I missed (all the stuff above seems way too complex and ugly for me).

where does inset2 come from ?

magrittr apparently

my bad, I forgot to import it in the beginning (now it's edited)

Here's another option relying on purrr::transpose():
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

tbl |>
  mutate(x = map2(x, transpose(pick(all_of(keys))), ~ c(.x, .y)))

Check identical:
identical(
  tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
      x = list(x %>% inset2('a', a) %>% inset2('b', b))
    ) |>
    ungroup(),
  tbl |>
    mutate(x = map2(x, transpose(pick(all_of(keys))), ~ c(.x, .y)))
  )
)
[1] TRUE


I'm thrilled to see this solution, really beautiful! Many thanks for the answer.

Here is a possible option using purrr::reduce and purrr::map2:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(magrittr)

tbl2 <- tbl %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    x = list(x %>% inset2("a", a) %>% inset2("b", b))
  ) |>
  ungroup()

tbl3 <- reduce(
  keys,
  \(x, y) {
    x[["x"]] <- map2(x[["x"]], x[[y]], ~ c(.x, list(.y)) |>
      set_names(c(names(.x), y)))
    x
  },
  .init = tbl
)

identical(tbl2, tbl3)
#> [1] TRUE


You can use metaprogramming to leverage your initial approach but have it dynamic rather than handwritten
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
keys <- c("a", "b")

tbl <-
  tibble(
    x = list(
      list(f = "foo", g = "bar"),
      list(f = "bar", g = "foo")
    ),
    a = list(
      list(i = 1, j = 2),
      list(i = 4, j = 7)
    ),
    b = list(
      list(i = 5, j = 3),
      list(i = 2, j = 9)
    )
  )

# handwrit
tbl2 <- tbl %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    x = list(x %>% inset2("a", a) %>% inset2("b", b))
  ) |>
  ungroup()

#dynamic from keys
(my_expr <- parse(text = paste0(
  c(
    "x",
    map_chr(
      keys,
      \(x)paste0('inset2("', x, '",', x, ")")
    )
  ),
  collapse = " %>% "
)))

tbl3 <- tbl %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    x = list(eval(my_expr))
  ) |>
  ungroup()

identical(tbl2, tbl3)


Ohh no no no. Please do not turn expressions to strings just to end up parsing them

Any reason why not ?

Here is a start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649979/what-specifically-are-the-dangers-of-evalparse

thank you but I'm not convinced by that.

There are many more sites that talk about this. eg why do you think there is NSE in R? people could simply make strings and evaluate them instead of doing NSE..

:) I'm not going to delete it.

Oo need to delete. I was not suggesting so, just letting you know. I used to code like that also.

I also post here my first working solution. All three answers so far are very interesting, I find the one from lotus the most concise and clear, I'll accept that one.
tbl2 <-
    tbl %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(
        x = list(modifyList(x, set_names(map(keys, ~extract2(.data, .x)), keys)))
    )

