# data table and data frame operations

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am using some R code that uses a data table class, instead of a data frame class.

How would I do the following operation in R without having to transform map.dt to a map.df?

```
map.dt = data.table(chr = c("chr1","chr1","chr1","chr2"), ref = c(1,0,3200,3641), pat = c(1,3020,3022, 3642), mat = c(1,0,3021,0))
parent = "mat"
chrom = "chr1"
map.df<-as.data.frame(map.dt);
parent.block.starts<-map.df[map.df$chr == chrom & map.df[,parent] > 0,parent];
```

Note:  parent needs to be dynamically allocated, its an input from the user.  In this example I chose "mat" but it could be any of the columns.

Note1: parent.block.starts should be a vector of integers.

Note2: map.dt is a data table where the column names are c("chr","ref","pat","mat").

The problem is that in data tables I cannot access a given column by name, or at least I couldn't figure out how.

Please let me know if you have some suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide sample data/a reproducible example (in this case, for the object `map.dt`)?

Comment: @Frank, I just added a short map.dt example thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear what the end goal is here, especially without sample data, but if you want to access rows by character name there are two ways to do this:

```
Columns = c("A", "B")
# .. means "look up one level"
dt[,..Columns]

dt[,get("A")]
dt[,list(get("A"), get("B"))]
```

But if you find yourself needing to use this technique often, you're probably using `data.table` poorly.

**EDIT**

Based on your edit, this line will return the same result, without having to do any `as.data.frame` conversion:

```
> map.dt[chr==chrom & get(parent) > 0, get(parent)]
```

Comment: There's also the eval-parse route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675182/in-r-data-table-how-do-i-pass-variable-parameters-to-an-expression/10676138#10676138

Comment: @SEnorO Thanks!, I just added an example of map.dt.

Comment: @SenorO, thanks, the problem is that I need to access them as a character, it's not always mat or pat, it changes.  I did map.dt[chr == chrom & map.dt[,get(parent)] > 0,get(parent)]; and it works, but I am curious to know why you think it's not a good use of a data table...

Comment: @SenorO I just added a note about the dynamic allocation of parent in the Q.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad use of `data.table` - I think if you find yourself doing it all the time it's a sign you're probably not using `data.table`  well.

Comment: @SeñorO awesome u re the master.

Comment: Glad I could help. The link @Frank posted is a good one to check out if you find using `get` is slow on data.tables with lots of columns.