# substitute into `j` element in data.table[, j , by]

Tags: r, data.table

I have:

```
DT = data.table(ID=rep(1:2,each = 2), Index=rep(1:2,times = 2), Close=3:6, Open=7:10)
```

My algorithm has earlier determined that the `DT` holds the time information in the column with name `Index`, hence the algorithm stores the following mapping:

```
time.col <- "Index"
```

Now the algorithm wants to perform a calculation that would be equivalent to:

```
DT[, list(Index, Value=cumsum(Close)),by=ID]
   ID Index Value
1:  1     1     3
2:  1     2     7
3:  2     1     5
4:  2     2    11
```

How to rewrite the line and plug the `time.col` variable in?

Neither of the following works:

```
DT[, list(time.col, Value=cumsum(Close)),by=ID]
DT[, list(substitute(time.col), Value=cumsum(Close)),by=ID]
```

Comment: `DT[, list(get(time.col), Value=cumsum(Close)),by=ID]` maybe? I'm not sure that is the accepted method for `data.table` though.

Comment: Interesting. Note that this doesn't preserve the column name: `names(DT[, list(get(time.col), Value=cumsum(Close)),by=ID])`  `[1] "ID"    "V1"    "Value"`

Comment: In this case, wouldn't it be better to use `:=`, since the number or rows will always be the same? That is: `DT[, Value := cumsum(Close), by=ID]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an expression for all of `j` in `DT`:

```
e <- parse(text = paste0("list(", time.col,",", "Value=cumsum(Close))"))

DT[, eval(e),by=ID]
```

**EDIT**

Or, if you store "Index" as a name, you can evaluate `time.col` within the environment of `.SD`:

```
time.col <- as.name("Index")

DT[,list(eval(time.col,envir=.SD), Value=cumsum(Close)),by=ID]
```

Very similar question here: [In R data.table, how do I pass variable parameters to an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675182/in-r-data-table-how-do-i-pass-variable-parameters-to-an-expression)

Also, this question helps to understand the mystery of non-standard evaluation in `data.table`:
[eval and quote in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913832/eval-and-quote-in-data-table?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the fastest solution from the above-mentioned `evals` is

`e <- parse(text = paste0("list(", time.col,",", "Value=cumsum(Close))"))
DT[, eval(e),by=ID]`

However, `:=` solution is even faster. See also Arun's note regarding copying.

**Dataset**

```
dim(DT); object.size(DT); DT

[1] 1354402       8
81291568 bytes
               Instrument       Date Open High  Low Close Volume Adjusted Close
      1:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-11   NA   NA 6.56  6.75 217200             NA
      2:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-12   NA   NA 6.66  6.88 616400             NA
      3:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-13   NA   NA 6.81  6.84 462000             NA
      4:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-16   NA   NA 6.81  7.00 306400             NA
      5:    GOOG/AMEX_ABI 1981-03-17   NA   NA 6.88  6.88 925600             NA
     ---                                                                       
1354398: YAHOO/TSX_AMM_TO 2014-04-24 1.56 1.58 1.56  1.58   2700           1.58
1354399: YAHOO/TSX_AMM_TO 2014-04-25 1.60 1.62 1.59  1.62  11000           1.62
1354400: YAHOO/TSX_AMM_TO 2014-04-28 1.59 1.61 1.54  1.54   7200           1.54
1354401: YAHOO/TSX_AMM_TO 2014-04-29 1.58 1.60 1.58  1.59    500           1.59
1354402: YAHOO/TSX_AMM_TO 2014-04-30 1.55 1.55 1.50  1.52  36800           1.52
```

**Benchmarking**

```
time.col <- "Date"
fun <- function(){
  out <- DT[, list(get(time.col), Value=cumsum(Close)),by=Instrument]
  setnames(out, "V1", time.col)
}

fun2 <- function() {
  DT[, Value := cumsum(Close), by=Instrument]
  out <- DT[ , c("Instrument", ..time.col, "Value")]
  DT[, Value:=NULL] # cleanup
  out
}

fun2. <- function() {
  DT[, Value := cumsum(Close), by=Instrument]
#   out <- DT[,c("Instrument", ..time.col, "Value")]
#   DT[, Value:=NULL] # cleanup
#   out
}

fun3 <- function() {
  DT[,list( eval(as.name(time.col),envir=.SD), Value=cumsum(Close)),by=Instrument]
}

fun4 <- function() {
  e <- parse(text = paste0("list(", time.col,",", "Value=cumsum(Close))"))
  DT[, eval(e),by=Instrument]
}
```

**Result**

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(fun(),
          fun2(),
          fun3(),
          fun4(),
          replications=200)

     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1   fun()          200    5.40    1.327      5.29     0.11         NA        NA
2  fun2()          200    5.18    1.273      4.72     0.45         NA        NA
3 fun2.()          200    2.70    1.000      2.70     0.00         NA        NA
3  fun3()          200    4.12    1.012      3.90     0.22         NA        NA
4  fun4()          200    4.07    1.000      3.91     0.16         NA        NA
```

Comment: See edit. Good point @Arun, made me realize that in the indicator objects that I will have, I should not store (modified) copies as subsets of original price data, but instead store only references to columns created with the `:=` on top of the large data. At the cost of pollution of the original dataset and later cleaning(`:=NULL`), when the indicator object is destroyed.